# How do I replace accented Latin characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, unicode, utf-8

I have an `ActiveRecord` model, `Foo`, which has a `name` field.  I'd like users to be able to search by name, but I'd like the search to ignore case and any accents.  Thus, I'm also storing a `canonical_name` field against which to search:

```
class Foo
  validates_presence_of :name

  before_validate :set_canonical_name

  private

  def set_canonical_name
    self.canonical_name ||= canonicalize(self.name) if self.name
  end

  def canonicalize(x)
    x.downcase.  # something here
  end
end
```

I need to fill in the "something here" to replace the accented characters.  Is there anything better than

```
x.downcase.gsub(/[àáâãäå]/,'a').gsub(/æ/,'ae').gsub(/ç/, 'c').gsub(/[èéêë]/,'e')....
```

And, for that matter, since I'm not on Ruby 1.9, I can't put those Unicode literals in my code.  The actual regular expressions will look much uglier.

Comment: even in 1.8 you can, use "ruby -Ku"

Comment: This problem has long since been solved and there are many great comments below. Re-reading it now, I want to make one thing clear: the idea was to create a version of the text that was searchable with just ASCII character, *not* to actually coerce the data. Note that there are two database properties: `name` and `canonical_name`. I do *not* advocate trashing the actual data, merely creating a way of searching through it without diacritic marks, which users of all languages often leave off.

Comment: Actually, every single of these is the wrong answer.  You need to use Unicode Collation Algorithm with a comparison strength set to level 1 only. Everything else is screwed up.

Comment: @tchrist so you showed up to the discussion to say "those guys are wrong" but didn't offer anything more than the barest of answers? o_O Please answer the question for real just so I can downvote you for being obnoxious.

Comment: @tchrist "wrong" may depend on individual requirements. True, being wrong may come back to haunt someone who doesn't know the ramifications (and consequently didn't add the requirement they would have added if they knew better). But until they are told said ramifications, they won't heed the suggestion.

Comment: @JamesA.Rosen I belive that you didn't have no intention to convert swedish/danish to some nonsense. I do get annoyed that some 'swedish' programmers referenced to this post as a way to implement/make  search (easier [for the programmer]) now almost 5 years later.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Rails has already a builtin for normalizing, you just have to use this to normalize your string to form KD and then remove the other chars (i.e. accent marks) like this:

```
>> "àáâãäå".mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'').downcase.to_s
=> "aaaaaa"
```

Comment: % ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i686-linux]

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that functionality existed in Rails. The method name was different in my Rails version: "àáâãäå".mb_chars.

Comment: +1 for form KD, which will also turn ligatures like 'ﬃ' to 'ffi'.

Comment: I'm trying to use this in another script outside a Rails app. I thought it'd be in `activesupport`, but after requiring it I still get a `NoMethodError` for `normalize`. Do you know what I have to require?

Comment: It is in activesupport, but you will have to do it like this:
  ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars.new("àáâãäå").mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'').downcase.to_s

Comment: This works great, but I had to do `mb_chars` like Christian. `foo.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'').to_s.split`

Comment: One more tip: if you get "NoMethodError: undefined method `normalize'", you may also need to explicitly set $KCODE = 'u' to force the default encoding for strings into Unicode.

Comment: At least in Rails3, String#parameterize works ... so "öüâ".parameterize == "oua"

Comment: Nope.  You need to use the UCA at level 1 for this problem.

Comment: I tested @foz solution and worked like a charm! I must add that parameterize is far cleaner and avoids future annoying warnings, i.e: `"àáâãäå".mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'').split(/a/)` shows "warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string" (it works anyway).
On the other hand `"àáâãäå".parameterize.split(/a/)` shows no warning

Comment: In essence, the beginning of this answer is what the `transliterate` method does, and if you add in the `downcase`, it's similar to what the `parameterize` method does.

Comment: parameterize is for urls -> it replaces spaces with `-` so not very useful for general use.

Comment: parameterize(' ') works outside URLs, too; it uses spaces instead if dashes.

In my case, I needed to preserve stuff like parantheses etc., so parameterize was not an option. The above mb_chars code resulted in the warning "regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string" (which is exactly what the regexp *wants to do* if I understood it correctly), so I also needed Kernel::silence_warnings. Which is ugly, but works.

Answer (score 101):

`ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate` (requires Rails 2.2.1+ and Ruby 1.9 or 1.8.7)

example:

`>> ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate("àáâãäå").to_s
=> "aaaaaa"`

Comment: You must `require 'active_support/inflector'` in non-Rails project (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17809800/407213) below)

Comment: You're the real mvp

Answer (score 44):

Better yet is to use I18n:

```
1.9.3-p392 :001 > require "i18n"
 => false
1.9.3-p392 :002 > I18n.transliterate("Olá Mundo!")
 => "Ola Mundo!"
```

Comment: in normal ruby (non rails) I get: LoadError: cannot load such file -- i18n rails library? Anyway as a note the rails method ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate actually calls the I18n one under the covers (after doing a normalize to make sure it can remove all diacritical marks)

Comment: For `cannot load such file -- i18n`, just `sudo gem install i18n`.

Comment: I got an error like `:en is not a valid locale (I18n::InvalidLocale)` until I added `I18n.available_locales = [:en]`. This also replaces non-ASCII characters that are not Latin letters with diacritics with question marks, so that for example `ruby -ri18n -ne'I18n.available_locales=[:en];puts I18n.transliterate$_'<<<Дあ☆` prints `???`.

Answer (score 20):

I have tried a lot of this approaches but they were not achieving one or several of these requirements:

- Respect spaces
- Respect 'ñ' character
- Respect case (I know is not a requirement for the original question but is not difficult to move an string to *lowcase*)

Has been this:

```
# coding: utf-8
string.tr(
  "ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåĀāĂăĄąÇçĆćĈĉĊċČčÐðĎďĐđÈÉÊËèéêëĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħÌÍÎÏìíîïĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłÑñŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøŌōŎŏŐőŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšſŢţŤťŦŧÙÚÛÜùúûüŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵÝýÿŶŷŸŹźŻżŽž",
  "AAAAAAaaaaaaAaAaAaCcCcCcCcCcDdDdDdEEEEeeeeEeEeEeEeEeGgGgGgGgHhHhIIIIiiiiIiIiIiIiIiJjKkkLlLlLlLlLlNnNnNnNnnNnOOOOOOooooooOoOoOoRrRrRrSsSsSsSssTtTtTtUUUUuuuuUuUuUuUuUuUuWwYyyYyYZzZzZz"
)
```

– http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/12938588984/remove-all-accents-and-diacritics-from-string-in-ruby

You have to modify a little bit the character list to respect 'ñ' character but is an easy job.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean about having to modify the character list to respect the character `ñ`? It seems to me that it is already in the list and aligned with `n`.

Comment: To respect the `ñ` character I mean to NOT transform it into `n` character but keep it.

Comment: I see. Can you say why this character is special (I mean, why it is singled out for respect)?

Comment: Could be a lot of reasons, the most common is that it is not an ASCII character.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand why you chose to single out `ñ` in your bulleted list of requirements. `ñ` is the "Latin small letter n with tilde", and it is in the extended ASCII set, along with many of the others in your list - see http://www.ascii-code.com/ - whereas there are a number of characters in your list that are *not* in the extended ASCII set, including `Ą` and `Ħ`. So I am still confused as to why you singled out `ñ`.

Comment: `ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate` seems to satisfy your requirements except for the "retaining ñ" and also this way is pure ruby which is nice. Unfortunately with unicode you can do weird stuff lik add an umlaut over basically *any* preceding char, so this approach will be hard to get comprehensive enough to meet all situations :|

Comment: Also, there are multiple different ways to have an 'ä', for example. Just bit me right now. `'ä'.ord => 97`, and `'ä'.ord => 228`. Won't work with copy-paste because StackOverflow does the sensible thing and normalizes them.

Comment: -1: Respecting just ñ is a too narrow requirement: The question is about transliterating *all* accented characters, not just those that you happen to know about personally. Actually Unicode gains new characters all the time, so even if your list is complete today, it may fail with the next Unicode release.

Answer (score 13):

My answer: the [String#parameterize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize) method:

```
"Le cœur de la crémiére".parameterize
=> "le-coeur-de-la-cremiere"
```

For non-Rails programs:

Install activesupport: `gem install activesupport` then:

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

"a&]'s--3\014\xC2àáâã3D".parameterize
# => "a-s-3-3d"
```

Comment: There is a vast difference with . parameterize versus ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate

    Input: " Don't Fall Into This Programming Trap"

   .parameterize gives:

   "don-t-fall-into-this-programming-trap"

    ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate gives:

    "? Don't Fall Into This Programming Trap"

That's a huge, huge difference.

Comment: @fuzzygroup Using the code formatting of markdown (e.g. `\`method\``) helps for the reading part of the comment. And to answer your question, `"Le cœur de la crémiére".parameterize` is the best UTF-8 to ASCII for urls, it's suuper nice and sweet

Answer (score 8):

Decompose the string and remove [non-spacing marks](http://ruby.runpaint.org/regexps) from it.

```
irb -ractive_support/all
> "àáâãäå".mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/\p{Mn}/, '')
aaaaaa
```

You may also need this if used in a .rb file.

```
# coding: utf-8
```

the `normalize(:kd)` part here splits out diacriticals where possible (ex: the "n with tilda" single character is split into an n followed by a combining diacritical tilda character), and the `gsub` part then removes all the diacritical characters.

Comment: See also unexist's answer here, which in essence does this but with a 1.8.x compatible regex.

Comment: This should be way higher. Other solutions completely strip other character sets (e.g. `I18n.transliterate('日本語') #=> "???"`) and `'日本語'.parameterize #=> ""`. This answer is the closest fit to my needs, which is to be able to approximately match diverse datasets on titles/authors. `'日本語 àáâãäå'.unicode_normalize(:nfkd).gsub(/\p{Mn}/, '') #=> "日本語 aaaaaa"`

Answer (score 7):

I think that you maybe don't really what to go down that path. If you are developing for a market that has these kind of letters your users probably will think you are a sort of ...*pip*. 
Because 'å' isn't even close to 'a' in any meaning to a user.
Take a different road and read up about searching in a non-ascii way. This is just one of those cases someone invented unicode and [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187582.aspx).

**A very late PS**:

http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding
http://www.w3.org/TR/charmod-norm/#sec-WhyNormalization

Besides that I have no ide way the link to collation go to a msdn page but I leave it there. It should have  been http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/

Comment: I'm all for database collation, but someone might switch databases a year after I leave; I'd prefer to be defensive and at least do it in code, and possibly also in the DB.  As for forcing the users to type what they mean: how many English users type résumé? Or "visual café"?

Comment: In the strip the poster has the letter å and ä. If you remove those to a the meaning of the word they are in are meaningless. You can't strip those and use what is left. If You really work for a European market you better learn to search with something, instead of trashing the users data.

Comment: In Slovak language, for example á, ä is very close to a. And so are all accented characters to those without accent. Lots of people don't use these at all in IM, etc.

Comment: @Vojto: In most nordern european languages, accented charachters are far away from the unaccented versions. In fact the are symbols of very different sounds.
The german öl for example (http://en.bab.la/dictionary/german-english/oel). Or the swedish words ål (eal) and al (a tree).

Comment: Cool, I just wanted to note, that that's not necessarily true for all European languages. I mentioned Slovak, but it's the same also for Czech, Polish, Croatian I guess and pretty much all Slavic languages.

And it's very important that search engines, etc. support searching by unaccented characters - because in most cases people are just too lazy to type accents.

Comment: You need to use a comparison based on the UCA for this, and at level 1 only, plus you need to use the UCA tailoring for the working locale if you want things to compare the way people in that locale are expecting if it differs from the standard collation.

Comment: @tchrist I (naively) thought that was precisely what I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

*This assumes you use Rails.*

```
"anything".parameterize.underscore.humanize.downcase
```

Given your requirements, this is probably what I'd do... I think it's neat, simple and will stay up to date in future versions of Rails and Ruby.

Update: dgilperez pointed out that `parameterize` takes a separator argument, so `"anything".parameterize(" ")` (deprecated) or `"anything".parameterize(separator: " ")` is shorter and cleaner.

Comment: Would't be ``"anything".parameterize(" ")`` shorter?

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know parameterize took arguments.

Comment: `.parameterize(" ")` is shorter, however, it down cases everything.  And I have found no way to append the `preserve_case`argument to the expression.  `I18n.transliterate`is most efficient and effective.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the text to normalization form D, remove all codepoints with unicode category non spacing mark (Mn), and convert it back to normalization form C. This will strip all diacritics, and your problem is reduced to a case insensitive search.

See http://www.siao2.com/2005/02/19/376617.aspx and http://www.siao2.com/2007/05/14/2629747.aspx for details.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285228/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-us-ascii-in-java#285791

Comment: All these answers involving normalization forms are every one of them wrong. You need a UCA level-1 comparison, possibly with locale tailoring.

Comment: See also Cheng's answer here

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use two columns in your database: `canonical_text` and `original_text`.  Use `original_text` for display and `canonical_text` for searches.  That way, if a user searches for "Visual Cafe," she sees the "Visual Café" result.  If she *really* wants a different item called "Visual Cafe," it can be saved separately.

To get the canonical_text characters in a Ruby 1.8 source file, do something like this:

```
register_replacement([0x008A].pack('U'), 'S')
```

Comment: Perhaps a nit, but the name 'canonical_text' would throw me a bit as what we're doing is lossy. I'd expect a name more like 'compatible_text' or 'decomposed_text' (although I can see the same argument against these, too). Perhaps just 'search_text'?

Comment: what is register_replacement here?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want Unicode decomposition ("NFD"). After decomposing the string, just filter out anything not in [A-Za-z]. æ will decompose to "ae", ã to "a~" (approximately - the diacritical will become a separate character) so the filtering leaves a reasonable approximation.

Comment: All these answers involving normalization forms are every one of them wrong. You need a UCA level-1 comparison, possibly with locale tailoring.

Comment: @tchrist: If you want to give an alternative answer, feel free. If you want to point out why my answer doesn't work, use can use a comment, but then at least point out _why_ it doesn't work. (Hint: read the title of the question first; UCA comparison does **not** replace accented characters).

Comment: See also Cheng's answer for an example

Answer (score 1):

iconv:

http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-talk-google/browse_frm/thread/8064dcac15d688ce?

=============

a perl module which i can't understand:

http://www.ahinea.com/en/tech/accented-translate.html

============

brute force (there's a lot of htose critters!:

http://projects.jkraemer.net/acts_as_ferret/wiki#UTF-8support

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2384

Answer (score 0):

I had problems getting the foo.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'').downcase.to_s solution to work. I'm not using Rails and there was some conflict with my activesupport/ruby versions that I couldn't get to the bottom of.

Using the ruby-unf gem seems to be a good substitute:

```
require 'unf'
foo.to_nfd.gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'').downcase
```

As far as I can tell this does the same thing as .mb_chars.normalize(:kd). Is this correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using PostgreSQL** => 9.4 as your DB adapter, maybe you could add in a migration it's ["unaccent" extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/unaccent.html) that I think does what you want, like this:

```
def self.up
   enable_extension "unaccent" # No falla si ya existe
end
```

In order to test, in the console:

```
2.3.1 :045 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT unaccent('unaccent', 'àáâãäåÁÄ')").first
 => {"unaccent"=>"aaaaaaAA"}
```

Notice there is case sensitive up to now.

Then, maybe use it in a scope, like:

```
scope :with_canonical_name, -> (name) {
   where("unaccent(foos.name) iLIKE unaccent('#{name}')")
}
```

The iLIKE operator makes the search case insensitive. There is another approach, using [citext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/citext.html) data type. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41691993/2553863) is a discussion about this two approaches. Notice also that use of PosgreSQL's lower() function [is not recommended](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/citext.html).

This will save you some DB space, since you will no longer require the cannonical_name field, and perhaps make your model simpler, at the cost of some extra processing in each query, in an amount depending of whether you are using iLIKE or citext, and your dataset.

**If you are using MySQL** maybe you can [use this simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813651/2553863), but I have not tested it.

Answer (score -3):

lol.. i just tryed this.. and it is working.. iam still not pretty sure why.. but when i use this 4 lines of code:

- str = str.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/,"")
- str = str.gsub(/[ ]+/," ")
- str = str.gsub(/ /,"-")
- str = str.downcase

it automaticly removes any accent from filenames.. which i was trying to remove(accent from filenames and renaming them than) hope it helped :)

Comment: It also removes all characters that aren't alphanumeric. Which is probably not the correct behavior, even for a filename.

Comment: This is not the expected behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately it removes all accented chars and doesn't replace them with their non accented equivalent :|