# How to search a string ignoring accent characters (e.g. ã = a)

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, non-ascii-characters, unicode-normalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programatic Accent Reduction in JavaScript (aka text normalization or unaccenting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccenting)

I'm trying to find a string ignoring accent, so in my example if I search for *avião* or *aviao* I get both result always.
here's a start up...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('input').keyup(function (event) {
                if (jQuery.trim($('input').val()) == "") {
                    return;
                }
                var str = jQuery.trim($('input').val()).split(" ");
                jQuery.each($('table > tbody > tr > td:last-child'), function () {
                    var colval = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
                    jQuery.each(str, function () {
                        var term = this.toLowerCase();
                        if (colval.indexOf(term) != -1) {
                            alert(colval);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="q" />
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>avião resume</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>résumé</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>resume</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>aviao résumé</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/teQvn/)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title to make it clearer, feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: @Martijn kind of - good find - but the premise, and the likely answer, are subtly different (string comparison vs. searching in a huge document)

Comment: @Pekka but using JS string comparisons; it's the same solution in the end.

Comment: @Martijn mmm, but the answer in the duplicate would mean having to normalize the entire document before searching  (as far as I can tell). Maybe that's the only way, but it's not nice. Maybe there is another way

Comment: @Pekka Until JavaScript supports proper unicode regular expression support I fear that's the only option you have :-/

Comment: @Martijn yeah, I see. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, at one point I had build this mapping of Latin-1 unicode codepoints to their ascii counterparts.

You would use this as:

```
var effectiveCharCode = CODE_NO_DIACRITICS[actualCharCode];
```

So, a string comparison method where <0 (s1 < s2), 0 (s1 == s2), >0 (s1 > s2) might be like:

```
function compareIgnoringDiacritics(s1, s2) {
  for(var i = 0; i < s1.length && i < s2.length; i++){
    var cmp;
    if((cmp = ((CODE_NO_DIACRITICS[s1.charCodeAt(i)] - CODE_NO_DIACRITICS[s2.charCodeAt(i)]))) != 0){
      return cmp;
    }
  }
  return s1.length - s2.length;
}
```

Here's the table:

```
var CODE_NO_DIACRITICS = [

            0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
           10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,
           20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,
           30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,
           40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,
           50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,
           60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,
           70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,
           80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,
           90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  65,  66,  67,
           68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,
           78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,
           88,  89,  90, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129,
          130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139,
          140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149,
          150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159,
          160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169,
          170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179,
          180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189,
          190, 191,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65, 198,  67,
           69,  69,  69,  69,  73,  73,  73,  73,  68,  78,
           79,  79,  79,  79,  79, 215,  79,  85,  85,  85,
           85,  89, 222, 223,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,  65,
          230,  67,  69,  69,  69,  69,  73,  73,  73,  73,
          240,  78,  79,  79,  79,  79,  79, 247,  79,  85,
           85,  85,  85,  89, 254,  89
    ];
```

Comment: forgive my naiveness but how is this going to help me? (CODE_NO_DIACRITICS['á']; returns undefined)

Comment: Well, that mapping uses char codes not characters (the example was perhaps misleading), so you would probably use String.charCodeAt() to get the character code value for each character in a string and then map that.  Like CODE_NO_DIACRITICS[someString.charCodeAt(0)].