# Not get the result when search using normal English, The data's are in Spanish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

Friends in my ionic application API return data's are  in Spanish language, I want to implement local search(sub string matching) in these data. Unfortunately accent/diacritics are does not match with normal character 
Eg. 'María', here 'í' is different from normal 'i'
    When I search using key word 'maria' i don't get the result.

How can I check 'í' is equal to 'i' and other characters.

Comment: Your question has been asked before. I googled 'javascript string search ignore accents' and found several StackOverflow answers: [Using JavaScript to perform text matches with/without accented characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700636/using-javascript-to-perform-text-matches-with-without-accented-characters), [string.search() that ignores accented characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115417/string-search-that-ignores-accented-characters), [How to search a string ignoring accent characters (e.g. ã = a)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5875389/1280867) and more

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I got that tums after posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of this question: [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)

I don't know how you are doing your search, but it's normal that you don't get any result with `í` and `i`, they don't have the same *ASCII* code.

What you can do during your search is replacing *temporary* all accents and diacritics in your search text and in your data text.

Comment: how to check ASCII code, the `í`  is only get from load server data
And used just sub string matching using indexof function

Comment: You don't need ASCII code. I just meant that it's normal that your search wasn't working, because those 2 chars are considered as different

Comment: I want to  consider it as same. How can I?

Comment: As I said, by replacing all accent/diacritics chars by normal char in your search method. But if you want more accurate help, you have to provide code...

Comment: Thanks zooly, I just replace the accent/diacritics by usual letter. Now it's working fine :-)

Comment: Happy that it helped you :)