# Replace accent characters in Velocity templates

Tags: velocity

In order to sort an array of strings in a javascript table effect using Velocity templates, I need to replace accent characters for normalized ones (i.e. 'é' for 'e'). I know to use replace method in Velocity but I would ask for something more sophisticated. XD

Comment: If you need this for JS, then you should do it in JS, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccenting

Comment: The result will be used in a Javascript script, but the information is stored in velocity variables, so I need the replacement in velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity is not the best tool when it comes to data manipulation, it was designed to display the data, not modify it. It is a templating language after all, not programming.

I would either strip accents on java side, or pass velocity var to javascript and strip accents there ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccenting)).

Comment: So this meants that in velocity there's no built-in method for replace accented character using bitmasks and regular expressions like in javascript. I couldn't have the same result with String.replace in velocity?

Comment: @Pymoo There is no built-in method in velocity, you can use `String.replace`, or build your own custom velocity directive (in java).