# ignore accent in regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ignore acute accent in a javascript regex match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054893/how-to-ignore-acute-accent-in-a-javascript-regex-match)

I have some javascript as :

```
var myString = 'préposition_preposition';
var regex = new RegExp("epo", "ig");
alert(myString.match(regex));
```

is it possible to match "épo" and "epo", if I set in regex only epo (or only épo)?

Comment: Follow the link. It is exactly the same question as yours, and there are useful answers. To avoid duplicates on this website, we "close as duplicate" if possible :)

Comment: Is it an option to strip the accents from the original string entirely before trying the regex match?  http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/

Comment: thank you, I will try implement my proper method with this exemple

Comment: Why not try replace? `alert(myString.replace('é', 'e'))`

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74122020/1202385 ... you can remove diacritics characters on the string to match instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. Regex operates with ascii, therefor special characters like `é` or `ß` are not recognized. You need to explicitely include those into your regex.

Use this:

```
var regex = /[ée]po/gi;
```

Hint: Don't use `new Regex()` it's rather slow, but declare the regex directly instead. This also solves some quoting/escaping issues.

Comment: problem is that I have two large text (french, english)
I search most standard method to ignore accent, execute matching and show results within lose original text

Comment: Well, you either need to replace those accents, (take a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228006/1047823)) or you always have to declare the character-classes manually, like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not achieve this behavior. RegEx match exactly the string you provided. How should the computer know when `épo` or `epo` is what you are looking for!

But you can specify a [class of chracters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that can be matched `new RegExp("[eé]po", "ig");`

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
var str = 'préposition_preposition';
str.match(/(e|é)po/gi);
```

Comment: Rather use character classes, that is what they are made for. Plus the matcher wont have to store the submatch.

Comment: why has the worst solution an upvote?

Comment: Does exist any method to ignore accent?

Comment: Valeriane as @clentfort said the regex is matching exact what you've said, we cant ignore é.