# How match string ignoring case and accent?

Tags: c#, regex

Im using Regex to match string ignoring case in Unity.

My code:

```
...
string _word = "Esto Es Una Cadena Con Texto"
string final = "esto es una cadena con texto"

if(Regex.IsMatch(final, Regex.Escape(_word), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)){
//
}
...
```

According this:

```
string _word = "Estó Es Uná Cadená Cón Textó"
string final = "esto es una cadena con texto"
```

Is there a code to match previous string ignoring case and accent?

Comment: Do you actually need regular expressions here? It may well change the answer very significantly.

Comment: I think you can safely drop the unity3d tag.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054893/how-to-ignore-acute-accent-in-a-javascript-regex-match

Answer (score 1):

Try using CultureInfo:

```
string _word = "Estó Es Uná Cadená Cón Textó";
string final = "esto es una cadena con texto";
var compareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
var equal = Convert.ToBoolean(compareInfo.Compare(_word, final));

if (equal)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match this specific sentence you could use something like this:

```
string final = "est[oó] es un[aá] caden[aá] c[oó]n text[oó]"
```

but if just want to "ignore" accents i would recommend you use String.replace(char, char)

```
string _word = "Estó Es Uná Cadená Cón Textó"
string final = "esto es una cadena con texto"

_word = _word.replace('é', 'e');  // same for á and ó

if(Regex.IsMatch(final, Regex.Escape(_word), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)){
//
}
```