# MongoDB query with Mongoose and Node.JS with a case and accents regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I'm trying to write a MongoDB query with Mongoose in Node.JS to get all names in a database matching a certain name. I would like that the query ignores the case and accents.

I looked around on the internet but couldn't find a query that does that.

MongoDB queries support regexes so that's what I'm trying to do.

This is what I have now. It works but doesn't match if the query or the queried string has accents and the other doesn't.

```
Passenger_record.find({$and: [{"FIRSTNAME": { $regex:req.query["firstname"], $options: 'i' }},{"LASTNAME": { $regex:req.query["lastname"], $options: 'i' }}]}).exec(function (err, person)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, [Programatic Accent Reduction in JavaScript (aka text normalization or unaccenting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccentin)

You'll find a function to build an accent insensitive regexp.