# A regex to highlight words in text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a function in Javascript which highlights words in text using. Takes around 20 lines of code.

```
highlight(text, pattern)
```

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/sR5wM/1/

Can anyone write a regex that would do the same more efficiently? The highlight function must be case insensitive, and ignore diacritics.

For Example:

```
highlight("Être ou ne pas être, là est la question", "etre la")
```

Would yield:

> **Être** ou ne pas **être**, **là** est **la** question

Comment: Related [Programatic Accent Reduction in JavaScript (aka text normalization or unaccenting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccentin)

Comment: Except those ugly regex  objects your code looks pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is provided by `Alex K.`, IMO I would suggest you to also have a look at the `UNICODE` based regex.

The below regex may not an optimized and closed to your expectation but will do exactly what you need or at least will give you a starter.

Try this regex:

```
([\u00C8-\u00CB]tre)|(l[\u00E0-\u00E5\u0061])
```

#### [Live Demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%28%5B%5Cu00C8-%5Cu00CB%5Dtre%29%7C%28l%5B%5Cu00E0-%5Cu00E5%5Cu0061%5D%29&input=%C3%8Atre%20ou%20ne%20pas%20%C3%AAtre,%20l%C3%A0%20est%20la%20question.l%C3%80)

*Notice the case-insensitive check box.*

Don't forget to look at the equivalent unicode [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) from the list.

Answer (score -2):

I dont remember the exact syntax of how it would look in javascript, but it would be something like

```
for(var input : inputs){
    string.regexReplace("("+input+")","<b>\1<\b>")
}
```