# Regular expression in javascript ignoring capital letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this variable:

```
var name = "Matemáticas"
```

And I would like to find in database, a model that it's name is either "Matemáticas" or "Matematicas" or "MATEMÁTICAS" or "MATEMATICAS" or "MatemátiCas" or "MatemaTicAs".

I try to do this:

```
var first_rg = name + '[a-zA-Záéíóú]'
var rg = new RegExp(first_rg, "g")
Theme.findOne({name: rg}, function(error, theme) {
}
```

But it doesn't work. I have not idea how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: You should tell us what ORM you're using.

Comment: Why would appending `[a-zA-Záéíóú]` to the name create a regex that ignores characters **in** the name? The regex `Foo[a-zA-Záéíóú]` still requires that the string start with `Foo`. (Also, if you're using the `i` flag, the `A-Z` part of your character class [or the `a-z` part, take your pick] is redundant.)

Comment: I added it because I think it is correct. I am using mongodb  and node

Comment: `gi` = global, case-insensitive...

Comment: If you are using MySQL you most likely don't need to do anything with the parameter as MySQL performs case-insensitive searches. Not too sure about the non-ascii characters, however.

Comment: If you're comparing in JavaScript, take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccentin  For SQL, check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14962419/5290909