# How to ignore accent in select2 search in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to search in select2

[image]

my customer uses spanish language which is included an accent. it should search word with `á` if some one type `a` it should ignore accent

is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programatic Accent Reduction in JavaScript (aka text normalization or unaccenting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227950/programatic-accent-reduction-in-javascript-aka-text-normalization-or-unaccentin)

Comment: No I am asking about select2 plugin