# Represent non-ASCII characters in URLS gives better page rank in search engines?

Tags: search-engine, friendly-url

Most part of the world uses non-ASCII characters. But some idioms use things like é, ö, á, ã, õ etc, which can be "converted" to ascii.

Suppose the title of the post is:

```
Configuração é fácil!
```

How to represent that in a URL?

```
www.myblog.com/post/1200/Configura__o-_-f_cil
```

A much better representantion is

```
www.myblog.com/post/1200/Configuracao-e-facil
```

Wikipedia do that as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deja_vu

Will this improve page rank in search engines?

How to do that in your favorite language?

Comment: So what are you going to do about Chinese characters? Or Japanese kana? Or the German scharfes S (ß)? I think you need to think about these things before implementing this feature.

Comment: Maybe one can just ignore a non ascii convertable character.

Comment: 'Scharfes S' (ß) is generally decomposed into two s's: Straße => Strasse

Comment: Check related articles: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331279/how-to-change-diacritic-characters-to-non-diacritic-ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331279/how-to-change-diacritic-characters-to-non-diacritic-ones)
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285228/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-us-ascii-in-java/285890#285890](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285228/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-us-ascii-in-java/285890#285890)

Comment: The problem with transliteration is that you might loose or change the meaning of the words. Take for example the german words *Buße* (engl. *penance*) and *Busse* (engl. *busses*) or *Maße* (engl. *measures*, *dimensions*) and *Masse* (engl. *mass*).

Answer (score 1):

## In Perl

Use  [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use utf8;
use Text::Unidecode;
print unidecode(
    "áéíóú\n"
);

# That prints: aeiou
```