# Replacing local characters?

Tags: php, text, locale, character

Is there any way to replace any foreign characters for example: ã, ä to a, Ĉ, ć to c etc.
I mean to leave simple letters like a-Z, without any additional things.

Comment: Tons of ways. Do you have a language with which you wish to accomplish this task?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Comment: The heading and the text of the question are contradictory, as the text refers to *replacing* characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this regular expression, if regexps are available to you:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); //Assuming it to be a Java String
```

If you wish to normalize your text, however, you should do as the accepted answer for this question suggests: [Remove diacritical marks (ń ǹ ň ñ ṅ ņ ṇ ṋ ṉ ̈ ɲ ƞ ᶇ ɳ ȵ) from Unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-cha)

If you need to achieve the same thing in PHP you can write:

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'asdaśćż,ąółwe,ÄĄ;ú');
```

Comment: This removes characters with diacritical marks _completely_, rather than "flattening" them to their ASCII equivalents.

Comment: The question DOES clearly state *removing* the characters, doesn't it?

Comment: I think the most important piece is: _ä to a, Ĉ, ć to c_

Comment: Ah, yes. Seems I did not read the question carefully enough. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Edited my answer to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the problem is, that I need to do it in php.

Comment: If found one solution, it seems to work quite well:
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'asdaśćż,ąółwe,ÄĄ;ú');

Comment: @Wojciech: pity you did not specify that 57 minutes ago. :)

Comment: @Wojciech: if that works for you, please add it as an answer so it can be available to future visitors. :)

Comment: @sarnold - you're right, but I've thought then about some general idea, I didn't know that it would be so simple :). I've tried to add it as answer, but i haven't got enough "points"

Comment: It's because you haven't accepted answers to 67% of the questions you've asked, so you've not gotten any reputations for it. :)

Comment: @Wojciech: I see. I've gone through some of your posts and added some reputation points, you'll get there quickly.

Comment: sarnold thanks:)! 
@MiladNaseri: it's because people didn't know or didn't answer to half of my questions :).

Comment: :) I see. Well, it's only fair that you shouldn't accept an answer unless it satisfies you. Anyways, we here are delighted to have you around.