# Compare strings in java ignore special characters

Tags: java, mysql, special-characters, string-comparison

please could you help me with comparing two strings with special characters in the same way as MySQL does it?
For example this two strings should be equal: "Dražík" and "Drazik"

Comment: You can probably get some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1453171/1343161).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **Collator** . See [Performing Locale-Independent Comparisons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html)

Comment: And since I'm using this comparison in equals method, do you know how to make hashcode for such a string? I mean how to get the same hash for both Dražík and Drazik.

Comment: Is OK to use for that myCol.getCollationKey("Dražík").hashCode() ?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably getting the Edit Distance/ [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) should resolve your issue. This is not an ideal solution but you may use it with significant success.

[Check it Your Self](http://www.csun.edu/english/edit_distance.php)

[Levenshtein Distance in Java](http://en.literateprograms.org/Levenshtein_distance_%28Java%29)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the s.compareTo(z) function where s,z are the string names.
It returns the difference between the first unmatched characters in the two strings