# Replace a character with different characters depending on which character it is

Tags: java, regex, string, diacritics

I have searched SO (and Google) but not found any fully matching answer to my question:

I want to replace all swedish characters and whitespace in a `String` with another character. I would like it to work as follows:

- "å" and "ä" should be replaced with "a"
- "ö" should be replaced with "o"
- "Å" and "Ä" should be replace with "A"
- "Ö" should be replaced with "O"
- " " should be replaced with "-"

Can this be achieved with regex (or any other way), and if so, how?

Of course, the below method does the job (and can be improved, I know, by replacing for example "å" and "ä" on the same line):

```
private String changeSwedishCharactersAndWhitespace(String string) {
    String newString = string.replaceAll("å", "a");
    newString = string.replaceAll("ä", "a");
    newString = string.replaceAll("ö", "o");
    newString = string.replaceAll("Å", "A");
    newString = string.replaceAll("Ä", "A");
    newString = string.replaceAll("Ö", "O");
    newString = string.replaceAll(" ", "-");
    return newString;
}
```

I know how to use regex to replace, for example, all "å", "ä", or "ö" with "". The question is **how do I replace a character using regex with another depending on which character it is**? There must surely be a better way using regex than the above aproach?

Comment: Would removing ALL diacritics work for you?...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-cha

Comment: Perhaps a regex with callback, but not your ordinary search-and-replace. Since Java doesn't have first-class functions, this will get unwieldy. Stick to what you have.

Comment: @Zutty Thanks, but my real problem is that I don't want them removed, but replaced depending on the character. Otherwise I would have done something similar to your proposal.

Comment: @Zutty Changed my mind, that linked question/answer actually contained the answer to my question. Since english isn't my native language, I didn't really know the word "diacritic", and thought the whole character would be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For latin characters with diacritics, a unicode normalization (java text) to retrieve basic letter code + diacritic combining code might help. Something like:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
newString = Normalizer.normalize(string,
        Normalizer.Form.NFKD).replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [StringUtils.replaceEach](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), like this:

```
private String changeSwedishCharactersAndWhitespace(String string) {
    String newString = StringUtils.replaceEach (string, 
      new String[] {"å", "ä", "ö", "Å", "Ä", "Ö", " "}, 
      new String[] {"a", "a", "o", "A", "A", "O", "-"});
    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there is not a common regex for replacing these characters at once. Apart from that, you can facilitate your replacement work by using a `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>()
                              {{put("ä", "a"); /*put others*/}};

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
    newString = string.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

Comment: you can squeeze out a few bytes by using `new HashMap<String,String>{{put("ä", "a"); ...}}()`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for good tip. Your snippet has a syntax error, anyway I included the correct version in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own mapper usen the matcher.find method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String from = "äöÂ";
    String to   = "aoA";
    String testString = "Hellö Wärld";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.format("[%s]", from));
    Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
    String result = testString;
    while (m.find()){
        char charFound = m.group(0).charAt(0);
        result = result.replace(charFound, to.charAt(from.indexOf(charFound)));
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

this will replace

```
Hellö Wärld
```

with

```
Hello Warld
```