# How can I convert accented characters to HTML symbol in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, charsequence

I wrote a program in Java that reads through a *Localizable.strings* file for iOS localization and creates the counterpart for Android. The iOS files allow special characters, like accented characters (è, é, etc), but for Android these should be converted to decimal unicode representation (and included in an xml file).

When I grab the value from the *Localizable.strings* file, I attempt to replace these symbols using the following code:

```
value = value.replace("...", "&#8230;")
             .replace("'", "\\'")
             .replace("’", "\\'")
             .replace("è", "&#232;")
             .replace("é", "&#233;");
```

This successfully replaces `...`, `'`, and `’`, but fails to convert the accented characters. I have read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-cha), but this does not address the same problem. What am I doing wrong, and how can I get this to work?

Comment: It works for me. If I input `èé...'’` it outputs `&#232;&#233;&#8230;\'\'`. [Working demo](http://ideone.com/eEfN2J). I think that the issue may be related to the file where you get the name from. Maybe you think you have `è` and `é` but you have similar characters, can you post a sample input?

Comment: The original file may contain these characters in some encoding, such as UTF-8 or MacRoman, and your Java program expects another encoding. Also possible: the characters may be decomposed into base character plus accent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

è:

```
&egrave;
```

é:

```
&eacute;
```