# Ordering an array with special characters like accents

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding

Does somebody knows how to order an array with words with special characters like accents?

`Arrays.sort(anArray);`

returns `'Albacete'` before `'Álava'`, and I want `'Álava'` before `'Albacete'`.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have to write your own `comparator` and pass it to `Arrays.sort()`. By default, Strings are sorted based on *Natural order*.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you just want to sort the strings as if they didn't have the accents, you could use the following:

```
Collections.sort(strs, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        o1 = Normalizer.normalize(o1, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        o2 = Normalizer.normalize(o2, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

Related question:

- [Remove diacritical marks (ń ǹ ň ñ ṅ ņ ṇ ṋ ṉ ̈ ɲ ƞ ᶇ ɳ ȵ) from Unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/%C5%84-%C7%B9-%C5%88-%C3%B1-%E1%B9%85-%C5%86-%E1%B9%87-%E1%B9%8B-%E1%B9%89-%CC%88-%C9%B2-%C6%9E-%E1%B6%87-%C9%B3-%C8%B5-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-cha)

For more sophisticated use cases you will want to read up on [`java.text.Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html). Here's an example:

```
Collections.sort(strs, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Collator usCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
        return usCollator.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});
```

If none of the predefined collation rules meet your needs, you can try using the [`java.text.RuleBasedCollator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).

Comment: (Note that you can change from `Collections.sort` to `Arrays.sort` if you're working with arrays and not lists.)

Comment: the `Normalizer.Form.NFD` very nicely sorted the french "accented E" to appear after the regular "E". Thanks !!

Comment: FYI: I found a problem with Normalizer.Form.NFD ... the polish "Ł" is sorted after Z, it's supposed to be after "L". This surprised me a lot because all the other accented letters sorted fine! I wonder if it's a bug.

Comment: confirmed, it's a bug. To fix it, you could switch to https://github.com/gcardone/junidecode but I didn't want to make my app larger, so I simply wrote a utility function `return Normalizer.normalize(src, form).replaceAll("Ł","L");`

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I know this is old, but would you mind sharing a link to the JDK bug with us? I was surprised to find this even with the newest JDK.

Comment: @PetrJaneček I'm sorry, but I don't have those notes any more. I faintly remember that polish character being the only issue

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [RuleBasedCollator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html)

> RuleBasedCollator class is a concrete subclass of Collator that
>   provides a simple, data-driven, table collator. With this class you
>   can create a customized table-based Collator. RuleBasedCollator maps
>   characters to sort keys.

RuleBasedCollator has the following restrictions for efficiency (other subclasses may be used for more complex languages) :

> If a special collation rule controlled by a  is specified it
>   applies to the whole collator object. All non-mentioned characters are
>   at the end of the collation order.

Answer (score 0):

use a comparator like the below :) and sort your list

```
Comparator<String> accentIgnorantComparator = (o1, o2) -> {
    return StringUtils.stripAccents(o1).compareTo(StringUtils.stripAccents(o2));
};
```