# Neo4j - search like query with non english characters

Tags: neo4j

Is there an option in neo4j to write a select query with where clause, that ignores non-latin characters ?

```
MATCH (places:Place)
WHERE (places.name =~ '.*(?ui)Fabergé.*')
RETURN places
```

I have place with Fabergé name in graph and i want to find it when user type Fabergé or Faberge without this special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an easy way to do this directly with a regex match in Cypher.

One possible workaround is to store the string in question in a normalized form in a second property e.g. `place.name_normalized` and then compare it with the normalized search string. Of course normalization needs to be done on client side, see another SO question on how to achive this: [Remove diacritical marks (ń ǹ ň ñ ṅ ņ ṇ ṋ ṉ ̈ ɲ ƞ ᶇ ɳ ȵ) from Unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/remove-diacritical-marks-%C5%84-%C7%B9-%C5%88-%C3%B1-%E1%B9%85-%C5%86-%E1%B9%87-%E1%B9%8B-%E1%B9%89-%CC%88-%C9%B2-%C6%9E-%E1%B6%87-%C9%B3-%C8%B5-from-unicode-chars)

Comment: so there is no option like in sql: COLLATE utf8_general_ci or any similar  ?

Comment: do you know maybe how to do it with regex ? or how can i use regex in Cypher query (because regex is not a problem, but don't know how can i use it in Cypher) ? Because giving place with normalized name it's not good workaraound especially when place will have name with more then one non english character, for example: Fébérgé. Normalize name will be Feberge but if user will type Febergé there will be no results :/