# Android "[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+" regex compilation fails (works localy)

Tags: java, android, regex, kotlin, collation

I am following the correct answer from here:
[Remove diacritical marks (ń ǹ ň ñ ṅ ņ ṇ ṋ ṉ ̈ ɲ ƞ ᶇ ɳ ȵ) from Unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/remove-diacritical-marks-%C5%84-%C7%B9-%C5%88-%C3%B1-%E1%B9%85-%C5%86-%E1%B9%87-%E1%B9%8B-%E1%B9%89-%CC%88-%C9%B2-%C6%9E-%E1%B6%87-%C9%B3-%C8%B5-from-unicode-chars/1453284#1453284)
to ,as you may expect, normalize some Strings.

It works great against local unit test, but when I try to use it on the emulator I get:

```
           Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
          [\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\p{IsLm}\p{IsSk}]+
              at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
              at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1340)
              at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1324)
              at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:946)
              at com.listonic.util.TextNormalizationUtilsKt.<clinit>(TextNormalizationUtils.kt:37)
                ... 7 more
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Remove all `Is` prefixes from the Unicode category names

Comment: BTW, for combining marks, you may use `\p{M}`, too.