# what's the simplest way to remove accent in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)
>   [Removing diacritics in Silverlight (String.Normalize issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046937/removing-diacritics-in-silverlight-string-normalize-issue)

I want to remove accent from a string in Silverlight application, for example, convert Renée to Renee. 
one way is try to use following APIs:

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString
```

but System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString is not available for silverlight framework.

what's is the simplest way to do it in C#?

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8` *is* available in Silverlight, although it's not clear how you'd use it...

Comment: A couple dupes can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769457/how-can-i-remove-accents-on-a-string)

Comment: those "dupes" aren't for silverlight

Comment: thanks. Normalize is not available to SL too.

Comment: @RobertLevy they seem to be quite standard .NET stuff, I don't know why they wouldn't work on Silverlight.

Comment: @KentZhou [here is a basic implementation of Normalize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046937/removing-diacritics-in-silverlight-string-normalize-issue)

Comment: @Lirik - ahh now there's a real dupe

Comment: @RobertLevy Silverlight is a .NET language...

Comment: @nominsim umm yeah but it doesn't have all the same APIs available.  Compare the answers in your links to the ones in Normalize's link.