# php is there a way to transfer Latin letters to english letters?

Tags: php, preg-replace

is there a way to transfer Latin letters to english letters with php?

Such as: `āáǎà` transfer to `a`,

`ēéěè` transfer to `e`,

`īíǐì` transfer to `i`,

... // there may be dozens which are main in Germany, French, Italian, Spain...

PS: how to transfer punctuation mark use php? I also want to transfer `%20` to a space, transfer `%27` to `'`. Thank u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iconv can usually do this for you:

```
iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $string);
```

Adjust source encoding to preference. The `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` part tells iconv to transliterate (replace with "similar" characters) whatever it can and ignore (leave out or replace with "?", can't remember) what it can't.

Comment: do u know how to transfer punctuation mark use php? I also want to transfer `%20` to a `space`, transfer `%27` to `'`? Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [How to change diacritic characters to non-diacritic ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331279/how-to-change-diacritic-characters-to-non-diacritic-ones)