# How to replace non-latin letters with PHP preg_replace function?

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php preg_replace with Unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059996/php-preg-replace-with-unicode-chars)

I have tried to solve this myself but failed.

I need to "clean" my string using PHP preg_replace so every character except a-z, A-Z, 0-9, space (' ') and latin letters "ČčĆćĐđŠšŽž" are removed.

I have learned how to solve first part of my problem: `$cleanstring = preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', $originalstring);`

But I'm not successful in including other latin letters in my pattern. I do not need all latin characters, just those listed above.

*Edit: When my $originalstring is "Đak", my $cleanstring is "272ak"! How can I fix this?*

Can anybody help?
Thank you in advance!

milosh

Comment: Instead of stripping the characters, you could also just [convert them to the ASCII letter without diacritics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881085/php-is-there-a-way-to-transfer-latin-letters-to-english-letters?rq=1).

Comment: I do not want to allow all latin chars with \p{L}, just those that are listed. Is there a way to just add hex values of these letters in my pattern? Also, is it posible to avoid /u, because I do not know if PHP is compiled with UTF support?