# C# Regex match a french special character

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

Is there a posibility to write a regular expresion to match a "c" or a "ç" to work for both examples like

```
var a = "ca va";
var b = "ça va";
Regex.Match(a,"\b(ca\sva)").Success // Match
Regex.Match(b,"\b(ça\sva)").Success // Dont match
```

Thanks

Comment: your code works correctly( after adding `@` to avoid compilation errors)

Comment: I've got 2 matches. And you're missing @ symbol before string constants in your regexes.

Comment: @L.B.: Not just compilation errors. Without the `@`, `\b` means "match a backspace character".

Comment: the problem is not in compilation, the problem is in matching. i want to match this "ça va" in both cases when users type "ca va" or "ça va"

Comment: @Constantine then use `@"\b([çc]a\sva)"`

Comment: Thanks @L.B, it was because of that @ :D, and because of RegExRX app where i validate the matches before using it in C#

Comment: How about transfer the special letter to English letter first? There's the idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/331321/1008230

Comment: I suggest you copy subject text into a temporary string, substitute each French character (`c` for `ç`, `ae` for `æ`, `e` for `è` and so on) for the English one, and then do your Regex match. If you need to match more than a handful of such phrases, you will quickly see that making each regex "general" like this will get out of hand. (Imagine writing 20 regexes, each with 3 variable characters like this.)

Answer (score 2):

For me, the following code returns true in either case:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace FrenchRegex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = "ca va";
            var b = "ça va";

            var regex = @"\b((c|ç)a\sva)";

            var matchA = Regex.Match(a, regex).Success;
            var matchB = Regex.Match(b, regex).Success;

            Console.WriteLine("Matches '" + a + "': " + matchA);
            Console.WriteLine("Matches '" + b + "': " + matchB);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I copied and pasted into VS2010, so you might need to do the same to reproduce my result.

In any case, I think a regex that matches both "ça va" and "ca va" would be `\b([cç]a\sva)`.

Comment: I'm not sure that's better. Not sure how the regex parser works under the hood, but I would think a character class ([]) would require more overhead, even if a small amount, than a group of literals separated by the pipe.

Comment: That's right, thanks! @BrianWarshaw I doubt in this case performance is more of a concern than readability, plus this way I don't introduce more backreference groups than the original version had.

Comment: I don't know . . . I think it's generally a good idea to keep them lean--better not to be in the habit of writing less-efficient expressions if you can help it. But that's my opinion, and I suppose I can stick it in my ear :-)

Comment: Well, for the sake of completeness: @BrianWarshaw is I believe suggesting `\b((c|ç)a\sva)`, which also works with the above code.