# How would I replace diacritical characters to normal alphabet?

Tags: .net, normalization

How would I replace diacritical characters to normal alphabet in .NET? I am trying to strip the accent off.

ÀÜÇ to AUC

Comment: looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331279/how-to-change-diacritic-characters-to-non-diacritic-ones?rq=1

Comment: But Ü is a **different letter** from U, and a perfectly 'normal alphabet' in the right context. Please [take heed of this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net#comment23803622_249087)