# UTF-8 -- ISO 8859-1 mapping tool

Tags: java, character-encoding

When I convert a UTF-8 String with chars that are not known in 8859-1 to 8859-1 then i get question marks here and there. Sure what sould he do else!

Is there a java tool that can map a string like "İKEA" to "IKEA" and avoid ? to make the best out of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285228/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-us-ascii-in-java

Comment: @Hasan Sorry I erroneously voted to close, after re-reading upvoted your question.

Comment: This question is not a dup! The suggest solutions works for US-ASCII only, but iso8859-1 contains also several letters like ÄÖÜ which should be distinguished from İ (Contained in utf-8 but not in iso8859-1)

Answer (score 1):

For the specific example, you can:

- decompose the letters and diacritics using compatibility form Unicode [normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)
- instruct the [encoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) to drop unsupported characters (the diacritics)

Example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// create encoder
CharsetEncoder encoder = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.newEncoder();
encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
// write data
String ikea = "\u0130KEA";
String decomposed = Normalizer.normalize(ikea, Form.NFKD);
CharBuffer cbuf = CharBuffer.wrap(decomposed);
ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(cbuf);
out.write(bbuf.array());
// verify
String decoded = new String(out.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
System.out.println(decoded);
```

You're still transcoding from a character set that defines 109,384 values (Unicode 6) to one that supports 256 so there will always be limitations.

Also consider a more sophisticated transformation API like [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) for features like transliteration.