# Removing accents/diacritics from string while preserving other special chars (tried mb_chars.normalize and iconv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, diacritics

There is a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225471/how-do-i-replace-accented-latin-characters-in-ruby) already. One of the solutions uses code like this one:

```
string.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^x00-\x7F]/n, '').to_s
```

Which works wonders, until you notice it also removes spaces, dots, dashes, and who knows what else.

I'm not really sure how the first code works, but could it be made to strip *only* accents? Or at the very least be given a list of chars to preserve? My knowledge of regexps is small, but I tried (to no avail):

```
/[^\-x00-\x7F]/n # So it would leave the dash alone
```

I'm about to do something like this:

```
string.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub('-', '__DASH__').gsub
  (/[^x00-\x7F]/n, '').gsub('__DASH__', '-').to_s
```

Atrocious? Yes...

I've also tried:

```
iconv = Iconv.new('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT') # Also tried ISO-8859-1
iconv.iconv 'Café' # Throws an error: Iconv::IllegalSequence: "é"
```

Help please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> it also removes spaces, dots, dashes, and who knows what else.

It shouldn't.

```
string.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^x00-\x7F]/n, '').to_s
```

You've mistyped, there should be a backslash before the x00, to refer to the NUL character.

```
/[^\-x00-\x7F]/n # So it would leave the dash alone
```

You've put the ‘-’ between the ‘\’ and the ‘x’, which will break the reference to the null character, and thus break the range.

Comment: Oh dear lord... please forgive me :)

Thanks!

Comment: yeah, we've all had a tedious load of debugging confusion caused by the simplest of typos!

Comment: What about the spaces? it's not preserving white spaces.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use the `transliterate` method. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate

Answer (score 2):

It's not as neat as Iconv, but does what I think you want:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2384

Comment: Snippet is gone