# Postgres accent insensitive LIKE search in Rails 3.1 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql, unaccent

How can I modify a where/like condition on a search query in Rails:

`find(:all, :conditions => ["lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%"])`

so that the results are matched irrespective of accents? (eg métro = metro). Because I'm using utf8, I can't use "to_ascii". Production is running on Heroku.

Comment: I would like to know, what solution did you use? Is there a rails-only based solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Proper solution

Since **PostgreSQL 9.1** you can just:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

Provides a function **`unaccent()`**, doing what you need (except for `lower()`, just use that additionally if needed). Read the [manual about this extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html).

More about unaccent and indexes:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

#### Poor man's solution

If you can't install `unacccent`, but are able to create a function. I compiled the list starting [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strip_accents_from_strings,_and_output_in_lowercase) and added to it over time. It is comprehensive, but hardly complete:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lower_unaccent(text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT lower(translate($1
     , '¹²³áàâãäåāăąÀÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄÆćčç©ĆČÇĐÐèéêёëēĕėęěÈÊËЁĒĔĖĘĚ€ğĞıìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏЇÌĨĪĬłŁńňñŃŇÑòóôõöōŏőøÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐØŒř®ŘšşșßŠŞȘùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮýÿÝŸžżźŽŻŹ'
     , '123aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaacccccccddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeggiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiillnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooorrrsssssssuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuyyyyzzzzzz'
     ));
$func$;
```

Your query should work like that:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ["lower_unaccent(name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%"])
```

For left-anchored searches, you can use an index on the function for *very* fast results:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_name_lower_unaccent_idx
  ON fest (lower_unaccent(name) text_pattern_ops);
```

For queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (lower_unaccent(name)) LIKE 'bob%';
```

Or use `COLLATE "C"`. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [Is there a difference between text_pattern_ops and COLLATE "C"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291250/3684)

Comment: hi Erwin, thanks for this. I'm on 9.1 so CREATE EXTENSION unaccent; seems like the way forward. How would you suggest i activate it through my rails app though (as i need this to happen on heroku as well as my dev environment)... thanks!

Comment: If you're stuck on 9.0, you can still install unaccent if you execute C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\contrib\unaccent.sql

Comment: (3 years later:) Heroku includes `unaccent`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search You can verify by running `echo 'show extwlist.extensions' | heroku pg:psql`

Comment: it worked beautifully. I inserted it on my rails application with a migration. Here's an awesome example of how you could do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611226/how-to-install-postgres-extensions-at-database-creation

Answer (score 23):

For those like me who are having trouble on add the `unaccent` extension for PostgreSQL and get it working with the Rails application, here is the migration you need to create:

```
class AddUnaccentExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "create extension unaccent"
  end

  def down
    execute "drop extension unaccent"
  end
end
```

And, of course, after `rake db:migrate` you will be able to use the `unaccent` function in your queries: `unaccent(column) similar to ...` or `unaccent(lower(column)) ...`

Comment: Verifying if the extension is not already present by doing so will prevent a migration crash:

```
def up
    execute "create extension if not exist unaccent"
  end
```

Comment: Slight typo - the correct code is: execute "create extension if not exists unaccent;" - exists is plural. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createextension.html

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you install postgresql-contrib. Then you connect to your DB and execute:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

to enable the extension for your DB.

Depending on your language, you might need to create a new rule file (in my case `greek.rules`, located in `/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/tsearch_data`), or just append to the existing `unaccent.rules` (quite straightforward).

In case you create your own `.rules` file, you need to make it default:

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY unaccent (RULES='greek');
```

This change is persistent, so you need not redo it.

The next step would be to add a method to a model to make use of this function.

One simple solution would be defining a function in the model. For instance:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    [...]
    def self.unaccent(column,value)
        a=self.where('unaccent(?) LIKE ?', column, "%value%")
        a
    end
    [...]
end
```

Then, I can simply invoke:

```
Model.unaccent("name","text")
```

Invoking the same command without the model definition would be as plain as:

```
Model.where('unaccent(name) LIKE ?', "%text%"
```

Note: The above example has been tested and works for postgres9.1, Rails 4.0, Ruby 2.0.

**UPDATE INFO**
Fixed potential SQLi backdoor thanks to @Henrik N's feedback

Comment: Danger! If you just string-interpolate the value into the SQL like that, and the value is user-provided, you're opening yourself up to SQL injections. This is safer since Rails will escape things for you: `Model.where("unaccent(name) LIKE unaccent(?)", "%#{value}%")` or just `Model.where("unaccent(name) LIKE ?", "%#{value}%")` if you don't care about unaccenting the value.

Comment: You are right, of course... I would not do this error now, but this is old.. I'll fix it, thanks for noting

Comment: No problem. Hm, I suspect using `unaccent(?)` for the column name will treat it as a string rather than a column name, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Not tested, I ended up using lucene solr, but it is OK to use strings as column names.

Comment: Anyone tried that on Cloud9? Can't find the usr/share folder... Looking around cloud9 forums as well. Nothing really useful coming up yet.

Comment: Figured a workaround for this.
1) Run cd `pg_config --sharedir`/tsearch_data to get to the right folder.
2) Found an updated unaccent.rules file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/postgres/postgres/master/contrib/unaccent/unaccent.rules
3) Edited and uploaded somewhere I have access to through a link.
4) Run sudo curl -O http://your-custom-link-here

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 questions related to your search on the StackExchange:
https://serverfault.com/questions/266373/postgresql-accent-diacritic-insensitive-search

But as you are on Heroku, I doubt this is a good match (unless you have a dedicated database plan).

There is also this one on SO: [Removing accents/diacritics from string while preserving other special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522715/removing-accents-diacritics-from-string-while-preserving-other-special-chars-tr).

But this assumes that your data is stored without any accent.

I hope it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Pierre - thanks - yes, i saw both of those, but unfortunately neither help me in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Foo` is the model you are searching against and `name` is the column. Combining Postgres [translate](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strip_accents_from_strings,_and_output_in_lowercase) and ActiveSupport's [transliterate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/transliterate). You can do something like:

```
Foo.where(
  "translate(
    LOWER(name),
    'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu'
  )
  LIKE ?", "%#{ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate("%qué%").downcase}%"
)
```