# Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?

Tags: sql, postgresql, localization, indexing, pattern-matching

In Microsoft SQL Server, it's possible to specify an "accent insensitive" collation (for a database, table or column), which means that it's possible for a query like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'João'
```

to find a row with a `Joao` name.

I know that it's possible to strip accents from strings in PostgreSQL using the [unaccent_string](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strip_accents_from_strings,_and_output_in_lowercase) contrib function, but I'm wondering if PostgreSQL supports these "accent insensitive" collations so the `SELECT` above would work.

Comment: See this answer for creating an FTS dictionary with unaccent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50595181/124486

Comment: Do you want case-sensitivity or case insensitive searches?

Answer (score 311, accepted):

## Update for Postgres 12 or later

Postgres 12 adds **nondeterministic [ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) collations**, enabling case-insensitive and accent-insensitive grouping and ordering. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-MANAGING)

> ICU locales can only be used if support for ICU was configured when PostgreSQL was built.

If so, this works for you:

```sql
CREATE COLLATION ignore_accent (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level1-kc-true', deterministic = false);

CREATE INDEX users_name_ignore_accent_idx ON users(name COLLATE ignore_accent);

SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'João' COLLATE ignore_accent;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4DBieoj6)

Read the manual for details.
This [blog post by Laurenz Albe](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/icu-collations-against-glibc-2-28-data-corruption/) may help to understand.

But ICU collations also have **drawbacks**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC)

> [...] they also have some drawbacks. Foremost, their use leads to a
> performance penalty. Note, in particular, that B-tree cannot use
> deduplication with indexes that use a nondeterministic collation.
> Also, certain operations are not possible with nondeterministic
> collations, such as pattern matching operations. Therefore, they
> should be used only in cases where they are specifically wanted.

My "legacy" solution is typically still superior:

## For all versions

Use the [**unaccent module**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) for that - which is completely different from what you are linking to.

> unaccent is a text search dictionary that removes accents (diacritic
> signs) from lexemes.

Install once per database with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

If you get an error like:

> ```
> ERROR: could not open extension control file
> "/usr/share/postgresql/<version>/extension/unaccent.control": No such file or directory
> ```

Install the contrib package on your database server like instructed in this related answer:

- [Error when creating unaccent extension on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100638/error-when-creating-unaccent-extension-on-postgresql)

Among other things, it provides the function `unaccent()` you can use with your example (where `LIKE` seems not needed).

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  unaccent(name) = unaccent('João');
```

### Index

To use an index for that kind of query, create an [index on the expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html). **However**, Postgres only accepts `IMMUTABLE` functions for indexes. If a function can return a different result for the same input, the index could silently break.

#### `unaccent()` only `STABLE` not `IMMUTABLE`

Unfortunately, `unaccent()` is only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`. According to [this thread on pgsql-bugs](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/201012021544.oB2FiTn1041521@wwwmaster.postgresql.org#201012021544.oB2FiTn1041521@wwwmaster.postgresql.org), this is due to *three* reasons:

1. It depends on the behavior of a dictionary.
2. There is no hard-wired connection to this dictionary.
3. It therefore also depends on the current `search_path`, which can change easily.

[Some tutorials](https://django-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orm-pg-fulltext.html) on the web instruct to just alter the function volatility to `IMMUTABLE`. This brute-force method can break under certain conditions.

Others suggest a [simple `IMMUTABLE` wrapper function](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAANrE7rpWjvZgdKX_hArNp8ynUezZ-Ehp8QEqC7hwfXuNqa91g@mail.gmail.com#CAANrE7rpWjvZgdKX_hArNp8ynUezZ-Ehp8QEqC7hwfXuNqa91g@mail.gmail.com) (like I did myself in the past).

There is an ongoing debate whether to make the [variant with two parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/unaccent.html#id-1.11.7.52.7) `IMMUTABLE` which declares the used dictionary explicitly. Read [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20120826134701.GM10814@momjian.us#20120826134701.GM10814@momjian.us) or [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAFj8pRDi0LRcmgyvd0ttC9J=VwOxe094fVRG2KTR_AQC86y-wg@mail.gmail.com#CAFj8pRDi0LRcmgyvd0ttC9J=VwOxe094fVRG2KTR_AQC86y-wg@mail.gmail.com).

Another alternative would be this module with an [IMMUTABLE `unaccent()` function by Musicbrainz](https://github.com/metabrainz/postgresql-musicbrainz-unaccent), provided on Github. Haven't tested it myself. I think I have come up with a ***better idea***:

### Best for now

This approach is **more efficient than other solutions floating around, and safer**.
Create an `IMMUTABLE` SQL wrapper function executing the two-parameter form with hard-wired, schema-qualified function and dictionary.

Since nesting a non-immutable function would disable function inlining, base it on a copy of the C-function, (fake) declared `IMMUTABLE` as well. Its *only* purpose is to be used in the SQL function wrapper. Not meant to be used on its own.

The sophistication is needed as there is no way to hard-wire the dictionary in the declaration of the C function. (Would require to hack the C code itself.) The SQL wrapper function does that and allows both function inlining *and* expression indexes.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.immutable_unaccent(regdictionary, text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
'$libdir/unaccent', 'unaccent_dict';
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_unaccent(text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT public.immutable_unaccent(regdictionary 'public.unaccent', $1)
$func$;
```

In Postgres 14 or later, an SQL-standard function is slightly cheaper, yet. Using the short form for a single statement:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_unaccent(text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
RETURN public.immutable_unaccent(regdictionary 'public.unaccent', $1);
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

Drop `PARALLEL SAFE` from both functions for Postgres 9.5 or older.

`public` being the schema where you installed the extension (`public` is the default).

The explicit type declaration (`regdictionary`) defends against hypothetical attacks with overloaded variants of the function by malicious users.

<sub>*Previously, I advocated a wrapper function based on the `STABLE` function `unaccent()` shipped with the unaccent module. That disabled [function inlining](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions). This version executes **ten times faster** than the simple wrapper function I had here earlier.

And that was already twice as fast as the first version which added `SET search_path = public, pg_temp` to the function - until I discovered that the dictionary can be schema-qualified, too. [Still (Postgres 12) not too obvious from documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/unaccent.html#id-1.11.7.52.7)*</sub>

**If** you lack the necessary privileges to create C functions, you are back to the second best implementation: An `IMMUTABLE` function wrapper around the `STABLE` `unaccent()` function provided by the module:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_unaccent(text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT public.unaccent('public.unaccent', $1)  -- schema-qualify function and dictionary
$func$;
```

Finally, the **expression index** to make queries *fast*:

```
CREATE INDEX users_unaccent_name_idx ON users(public.f_unaccent(name));
```

Remember to **recreate indexes** involving this function after any change to function or dictionary, like an in-place major release upgrade that would not recreate indexes. Recent major releases all had updates for the `unaccent` module.

Adapt queries to match the index (so the query planner will use it):

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE  f_unaccent(name) = f_unaccent('João');
```

We don't need the function in the expression to the right of the operator. There we can also supply unaccented strings like `'Joao'` directly.

The faster function does not translate to much faster queries using the **[expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html)**. Index look-ups operate on pre-computed values and are very fast either way. But index maintenance and queries not using the index benefit. And access methods like [bitmap index scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) may have to *recheck* values in the heap (the main relation), which involves executing the underlying function. See:

- ["Recheck Cond:" line in query plans with a bitmap index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/106264/3684)

Security for client programs has been tightened with Postgres 10.3 / 9.6.8 etc. You *need* to schema-qualify function and dictionary name as demonstrated when used in any indexes. See:

- ['text search dictionary “unaccent” does not exist' entries in postgres log, supposedly during automatic analyze](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202490/text-search-dictionary-unaccent-does-not-exist-entries-in-postgres-log-supp?noredirect=1#comment421020_202490)

#### Ligatures

In Postgres **9.5 or older** ligatures like 'Œ' or 'ß' have to be expanded manually (if you need that), since `unaccent()` always substitutes a *single* letter:

```
SELECT unaccent('Œ Æ œ æ ß');

unaccent
----------
E A e a S
```

You will love [this update to unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/201012021544.oB2FiTn1041521@wwwmaster.postgresql.org#201012021544.oB2FiTn1041521@wwwmaster.postgresql.org) in Postgres **9.6**:

> Extend `contrib/unaccent`'s standard `unaccent.rules` file to handle all
> diacritics known to Unicode, and **expand ligatures correctly** (Thomas
> Munro, Léonard Benedetti)

Bold emphasis mine. Now we get:

```
SELECT unaccent('Œ Æ œ æ ß');

unaccent
----------
OE AE oe ae ss
```

#### Pattern matching

For **`LIKE`** or **`ILIKE`** with arbitrary patterns, combine this with the module [**`pg_trgm`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) in PostgreSQL 9.1 or later. Create a trigram GIN (typically preferable) or GIST expression index. Example for GIN:

```
CREATE INDEX users_unaccent_name_trgm_idx ON users
USING gin (f_unaccent(name) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Can be used for queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE  f_unaccent(name) LIKE ('%' || f_unaccent('João') || '%');
```

GIN and GIST indexes are more expensive (to maintain) than plain B-tree:

- [Difference between GiST and GIN index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975517/difference-between-gist-and-gin-index/28976555#28976555)

There are simpler solutions for just left-anchored patterns. More about pattern matching and performance:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

`pg_trgm` also provides useful [operators for "similarity" (`%`) and "distance" (`<->`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE).

Trigram indexes also support simple regular expressions with `~` et al. and **case insensitive** pattern matching with `ILIKE`:

- [PostgreSQL accent + case insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627951/postgresql-accent-case-insensitive-search/28636000#28636000)

Comment: In your solution, are indexes used, or would I need to create an index on `unaccent(name)`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter In psql 9.1.4, I get "functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE", because of the unaccent function is STABLE, instead of INMUTABLE. What do you recommend?

Comment: @e3matheus: Feeling guilty for not having tested the previous solution I provided, I investigated and updated my answer with a new and better  (IMHO) solution for the problem than what is floating around so far.

Comment: Isn't the collation `utf8_general_ci` the answer for this kind of issues?

Comment: @Med: This would apply to **MySQL** and the [better choice would be `utf8_unicode_ci` there..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Comment: Thank you for such a quality answer, you really covered every possibility. Even after reading the thread, I still don't understand why they didn't make it IMMUTABLE. Unaccenting *doesn't* depend on a dictionary, all rules are stored in my Postgres directory under share/postgresql/tsearch_data/unaccent.rules, so I'm positive it's the same for every dictionary. And why would it change anyway, maybe I'll have some foreign words in English.

Comment: Can we use `varchar_pattern_ops` instead of `gin_trgm_ops`?

Comment: @Teejay: It depends. Please ask your question in a new question, comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: @DanielSerodio: Consider the update. Should make it much faster, yet.

Comment: I wonder if accent-insensitive is now possible with ICU collations.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I didn't have time to test it out, yet, but that's an intended use case.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter using pg_dump and pg_restore I get this error:

pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  text search dictionary "public.unaccent" does not exist
LINE 2:   SELECT public.immutable_unaccent(regdictionary 'public.una...

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: @phlegx: You probably did not install the additional module unaccent (as instructed at the top) in the target database - or installed it to a different schema.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter my file created with pg_dump (pg_dump -Fc -b -f /tmp/dump.sql db_dev) includes CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent WITH SCHEMA public;
DROP EXTENSION unaccent; Why pg_dump adds the drop?

Comment: @phlegx: Not sure why. But if the drop comes after the create, that would explain the problem.

Answer (score 15):

## No, PostgreSQL does not support collations in that sense

PostgreSQL does not support collations like that (accent insensitive or not) because no comparison can return equal unless things are binary-equal. This is because internally it would introduce a lot of complexities for things like a hash index. For this reason collations in their strictest sense **only affect ordering** and not equality.

## Workarounds

### Full-Text-Search Dictionary that Unaccents lexemes.

For FTS, you can define your own dictionary using `unaccent`,

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mydict ( COPY = simple );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mydict
  ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word
  WITH unaccent, simple;
```

Which you can then index with a functional index,

```
-- Just some sample data...
CREATE TABLE myTable ( myCol )
  AS VALUES ('fóó bar baz'),('qux quz');

-- No index required, but feel free to create one
CREATE INDEX ON myTable
  USING GIST (to_tsvector('mydict', myCol));
```

You can now query it very simply

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE to_tsvector('mydict', myCol) @@ 'foo & bar'

    mycol    
-------------
 fóó bar baz
(1 row)
```

See also

- [Creating a case-insensitive and accent/diacritics insensitive search on a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177044/2639)

### Unaccent by itself.

The [`unaccent` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html) can also be used by itself without FTS-integration, for that check out [Erwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/124486)

Comment: Note that the opening paragraph here is no longer strictly true as of Postgres 12 which introduced [nondeterministic collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#COLLATION-NONDETERMINISTIC). However they're still not supported by pattern matching operators.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure PostgreSQL relies on the underlying operating system for collation.  It *does* support [creating new collations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createcollation.html), and [customizing collations](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2010-10/msg02063.php). I'm not sure how much work that might be for you, though. (Could be quite a lot.)

Comment: New collation support is currently basically limited to wrappers and aliases for operating system locales. It's very basic. There's no support for filter functions, custom comparators, or any of what you'd need for true custom collations.