# How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, concatenation, coalesce

I have two string columns `a` and `b` in a table `foo`.

`select a, b from foo` returns values `a` and `b`.  However, concatenation of `a` and `b` does not work. I tried :

```
select a || b from foo
```

and

```
select  a||', '||b from foo
```

Update from comments: both columns are type `character(2)`.

Comment: ... or another `text` type?

Comment: @acfrancis Since OP says `concatenate` I doubt that he's dealing with numeric types, though PostgreSQL would take care of some of them as well.  See here:http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Yes, these columns are character(2). "+" does not work - " No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL? Here are docs for 9.1: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html. See my example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/182

Comment: You probably have a syntax error in your query not related to concatenation.

Comment: Please be specific. When you say it "does not work", what *exactly* does that mean? Error message please, and *exact original SQL* to go with it. Also, `character` is an awful data type, avoid it whenever possible in favour of `varchar` or `text`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem was in nulls in the values; then the concatenation does not work with nulls.  The solution is as follows:

```
SELECT coalesce(a, '') || coalesce(b, '') FROM foo;
```

Answer (score 355):

With [string types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) (including `character(2)`), the displayed concatenation just works because, [quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

> [...] the string concatenation operator (`||`) accepts non-string
> input, so long as **at least one input is of a string type**, as shown in
> [Table 9.8](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL). For other cases, insert an explicit coercion to `text` [...]

Bold emphasis mine. The 2nd example `select  a||', '||b from foo` works for *any* data types because the untyped string literal `', '` defaults to type `text` making the whole expression valid.

For non-string data types, you can "fix" the 1st statement by [casting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) at least one argument to `text`. *Any* type can be cast to `text`.

```
SELECT a::text || b AS ab FROM foo;
```

Judging from [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19958775/939860), "*does not work*" was supposed to mean *"returns null"*. The result of *anything* concatenated to null is null. If **`null`** values can be involved and the result shall not be null, use [**`concat_ws()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to concatenate any number of values:

```
SELECT concat_ws(', ', a, b) AS ab FROM foo;
```

Separators are only added between non-null values, i.e. only where necessary.

Or **[`concat()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)** if you don't need separators:

```
SELECT concat(a, b) AS ab FROM foo;
```

No need for type casts since both functions take [`"any"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html#DATATYPE-PSEUDOTYPES-TABLE) input and work with text representations. **However**, that's also why the [function volatility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) of both `concat()` and `concat_ws()` is only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`. If you need an **immutable function** (like for an index, a generated column, or for partitioning), see:

- [Create an immutable clone of concat_ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372666/create-an-immutable-clone-of-concat-ws/54384767#54384767)
- [PostgreSQL full text search on many columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164081/3684)

More details (and why `COALESCE` is a poor substitute) in this related answer:

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/postgresql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)

#### Asides

`+` (as mentioned in comments) is not a valid operator for string concatenation in Postgres (or standard SQL). It's a private idea of Microsoft to add this to their products.

There is hardly any good reason to use <strike>`character(n)`</strike> (synonym: <strike>`char(n)`</strike>). Use [`text` or `varchar`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html). Details:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)
- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

Comment: Thank you.  The 1st version does not work with null and the 2nd gave me the error for concat_ws:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: You did see `Postgres 9.1 or later`, right? You should have provided your version of Postgres to begin with, *in the question*. Please *update your question* with all the requested information, before you come back for anything else.

Comment: Thank you, the solution I found works for any Postgres version

Comment: `SELECT concat(a, b) FROM foo;` works for me in Postgres 9.3 when `a` and `b` are `VARCHAR`s.

Answer (score 32):

it is better to use CONCAT function in PostgreSQL  for concatenation

eg : `select CONCAT(first_name,last_name)  from person where pid = 136`

if you are using column_a || ' ' || column_b for concatenation for 2 column , if any of the value in column_a or column_b is null query will return null value.
which may not be preferred in all cases.. so instead of this

> ||

use

> CONCAT

it will return relevant value if either of them have value

Comment: Worked for me. Happily found I could add a space between too: 
`CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)`

Comment: this should be the right answer because concat accepts null

Answer (score 14):

As i was also stuck in this, think i should share the solution that worked best for me. I also think that this is much simpler.

If you use Capitalized table name.

```
SELECT CONCAT("firstName", ' ', "lastName") FROM "User"
```

If you use lowercase table name

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) FROM user
```

That's it!. As PGSQL counts Double Quote for column declaration and Single Quote for string, this works like a charm.

Comment: If there can be NULL values, this expression produces a leading or trailing space. Typically not what you want. Use `concat_ws()` instead.

Answer (score 12):

CONCAT functions sometimes not work with older postgreSQL version

see what I used to solve problem without using CONCAT

```
 u.first_name || ' ' || u.last_name as user,
```

Or also you can use

```
 "first_name" || ' ' || "last_name" as user,
```

in second case I used double quotes for first_name and last_name

Hope this will be useful, thanks

Comment: if my first name or last name is null then concat value also showing null

Answer (score 0):

**PHP's Laravel framework,**
***I am using search first_name, last_name Fields consider like Full Name Search***

> Using || symbol Or concat_ws(), concat() methods

```
$names = str_replace(" ", "", $searchKey);                               
$customers = Customer::where('organization_id',$this->user->organization_id)
             ->where(function ($q) use ($searchKey, $names) {
                 $q->orWhere('phone_number', 'ilike', "%{$searchKey}%"); 
                 $q->orWhere('email', 'ilike', "%{$searchKey}%");
                 $q->orWhereRaw('(first_name || last_name) LIKE ? ', '%' . $names. '%');
    })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(20);
```

This worked charm!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select concat_ws(' ', FirstName, LastName) AS Name from person;
```

Comment: `concat_ws(' ', FirstName, LastName)` would be much cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

For example if there is employee table which consists of columns as:

```
employee_number,f_name,l_name,email_id,phone_number
```

if we want to concatenate `f_name + l_name` as `name`.

```
SELECT employee_number,f_name ::TEXT ||','|| l_name::TEXT  AS "NAME",email_id,phone_number,designation FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: What does this answer add over existing answers?

Answer (score -2):

You can also use a pipe for this operation.

```
Select EmployeeID ,FirstName ||' ' || LastName as Full_Name from Employees
order by EmployeeID
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Nor does it add anything useful.