# SQL JOIN ON # = chr#

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a Postgres DB with some very bad schema design, I'm trying to join two tables with and ID and a field which has the ID but with a couple of characters at the beginning, how would I join these?

eg.

```
TABLE1
------
Field name: ID
Value: 1000

TABLE2
------
Field name: NUMBER
Value: WO-1000
```

so basically I need it to say something like:

```
JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.ID = 'WO-' + TABLE2.NUMBER)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `||` operator to `concatenate` two values in Postgres. Try this.

```
JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.ID = 'WO-' ||  TABLE2.NUMBER)
```

If your `Number` column is of `Integer` type then `cast` it to `text`.

```
JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.ID = 'WO-' ||  cast(TABLE2.NUMBER as text)) --or TABLE2.NUMBER::text
```

Check [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-postgresql-select) for more info

Comment: The `||` is not specific to Postgres - this is what has been defined in the SQL standard 30 years ago

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Yep that's a sql standard. Was just mentioning its a way to concatenate :)