# Postgresql concat columns and skip column if column in NULL or is empty string

Tags: sql, database, string, postgresql, sql-null

I am trying to concatenate a number of columns and skip the column if column is NULL OR empty in postgres. For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(coalesce('a',''),
        '|',coalesce('b',''),
        '|',coalesce(NULL,''),
        '|',coalesce('',''),
        '|',coalesce('',''),
        '|',coalesce('c','')) AS finalstring;
```

Output : `a|b||||c`

Expected output : `a|b|c`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19942824/939860

Answer (score 10):

Use [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.9.7.2.2.5.1.1), which ignores `null` values:

```
concat_ws('|', col1, col2, col3, ...)
```

If you want to ignore empty strings as well, then you can use `nullif()`:

```
concat_ws('|', nullif(col1, ''), nullif(col2, ''), nullif(col3, ''), ...)
```