# How to append to the value of a given key in a json column?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have `user_product_mapping` storing product per user:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_product_mapping;
CREATE TABLE user_product_mapping 
(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT,
    product_info json NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

Sample values:

```
INSERT INTO user_product_mapping (user_id, product_info)
VALUES
(1, '{"product": "laptop,mobile"}'),
(2, '{"product": "charger"}'),
(3, '{"product": "mobile,mouse,charger"}')
;
```

Now I want to add a new product as 'laptop' to existing user_id 2.
Expected result:

```
user_id | product_info
---------------------------------------
      2 | {"product": "charger,laptop"}
```

I have tried to append but face an issue:

```
UPDATE user_product_mapping
SET product_info = product_info || '{"laptop"}'
WHERE user_id = 2;

Error: 
ERROR:  column "product_info" is of type json but expression is of type text
LINE 2: SET product_info = product_info || '{"123e4567-e89b-12d3-a45...
                           ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Can you please suggest the way forward.

Comment: Use `'{"laptop"}'::json` instead, otherwise the `||` expression is doing string concatenation

Comment: You probably should use an array of product infos, not a comma-delimited string. It's much more complicated with the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE user_product_mapping
SET    product_info = json_build_object('product', concat_ws(',', NULLIF(product_info->>'product', ''), 'laptop'))
WHERE  user_id = 2;
```

Even works properly with a missing 'product' key, one with a null value, or an empty list. But it's putting lipstick on a pig.

It burns down to extracting the text value, concatenating another item to the list (safely), and assigning a newly wrapped JSON value. See:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select/19943343#19943343)

While using JSON, the [data type `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) would be more practical, so you can use [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
UPDATE ...
SET    product_info = jsonb_set (product_info, '{product}', to_jsonb(concat_ws(',', NULLIF(product_info->>'product', ''), 'laptop')))
```

More practical, yet, with a JSON array instead of that list of text values.

```
UPDATE ...
SET product_info = product_info || jsonb '"laptop"'
```

And that would be more practical as Postgres array of text: `text[]`, yet.

```
UPDATE ...
SET    product_info = product_info || 'laptop'
```

But what you probably really should do is a properly normalized many-to-many implementation:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)
- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb/26704636#26704636)

Then you add and remove products with a plain `INSERT` or `DELETE`, not causing problems with concurrent writes for the same user like all of the above will.