# Build comma-separated list of qualifying column names

Tags: sql, postgresql, export-to-csv, string-concatenation

I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fruits (
    id int,
    apple varchar(50),
    pear varchar(50),
    orange varchar(50),
    grapes varchar(50),
    banana varchar(500)
);

INSERT INTO fruits(id, apple, pear, orange, grapes, banana)
VALUES (51,0,1,0,0,0), (52,0,1,0,0,1), (53,1,0,1,0,1),(54,1,0,0,0,1);
```

So that:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM fruits

id  apple   pear    orange  grapes  banana
------------------------------------------
51    0      1        0       0      0
52    0      1        0       0      1
53    1      0        1       0      1
54    1      0        0       0      1
```

I want to select the column names for which the value is `1`, into a tab-separated csv file.

Intended file format:

```
51  pear
52  pear,banana
53  apple,orange,banana
54  apple,banana
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of `CASE` expressions, wrapped in [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to deal with null values properly:

```sql
SELECT id
     , concat_ws( ', '
        , CASE WHEN apple  = '1' THEN 'apple'  END
        , CASE WHEN pear   = '1' THEN 'pear'   END
        , CASE WHEN orange = '1' THEN 'orange' END
        , CASE WHEN banana = '1' THEN 'banana' END) AS fruit_list
FROM   fruits;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/myHCRRvQ)

See:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select/19943343#19943343)

Of course, your columns should rather be `boolean` instead of `varchar` to begin with. Then it could be just:

```
CASE WHEN apple THEN 'apple' END
```

Comment: If want  tab separated csv do not need separate queries just use  query in this answer  and when  export to csv select delimiter as tab.