# Update column by joining both colums

Tags: postgresql

I want to update my column by joining both column to one.

| FirstName | Name |
| --- | --- |
| John | Kowalsky |
| Adam | Smith |
| null | Bush |

I would like to achieve such an effect in column

"Name

John Kowalsky
Adam Smith
Bush

I tried subselect but dont work

Comment: which query did you try? Can you include it in your question? Also maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select

Answer (score 1):

No sub-select required:

```
update the_table
   set name = concat_ws(' ', firstname, name);
```

But updating the column this way is a bad idea as you lose the real (last) name.

I would put this into a view:

```
create view the_table_with_full_name
as
select name, firstname, concat_ws(' ', firstname, name) as full_name
from the_table;
```

`concat_ws()` will properly deal with nulls or empty strings

Comment: But i need to update column values. In next step i decided to remove whole FirstName column

Comment: Removing the firstname column is an even worse idea.

Comment: why? I dont need anymore this column

Comment: You want to store the firstname and the lastname of a person. Those should be in **two** columns, not munged together in one. This one of the most basic rules of good database design.