# Inner Join Help on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, relationship

I have the following database relationship and query for PostgreSQL below:

[image]

```
create table gender(
    gender_id int primary key,
    gender char(10))

create table student(
    student_id int primary key,
    first_name char(50) not null,
    last_name char(50) not null,
    gender_id int not null,
    constraint gender_fk foreign key(gender_id) references gender(gender_id))

insert into gender values(1, 'Male');
insert into gender values(2, 'Female');
insert into gender values(3, 'Other');
insert into student values(101, 'John', 'Smith', 1);
insert into student values(102, 'Sara', 'Bradford', 2);
insert into student values(103, 'Joseph', 'Brown', 1);
insert into student values(104, 'David', 'Lopez', 3);
```

**TABLE** Student: [image]

**TABLE** Gender: [image]

How do I create an inner join statement that ***checks if the student's gender is 'Female'?***

All other genders ('Male' and 'Other') will just have null value. I want an output like the following inner-joined table:

[image]

Comment: There are two parts, first of do an normal inner join.  Then use the Case statement in the selection part  https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case/

Answer (score 3):

We don't even need to involve the `gender` table:

```sql
SELECT student_id, first_name || ' ' || last_name AS full_name
     , CASE WHEN gender_id = 2 THEN 'Female' END AS chk_female
FROM   student;
```

[SQL `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) defaults to `null`, when the `ELSE` part is missing.

If you insist on a join, rather use [`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) and filter for 'Female' in the join condition. Then all other genders default to `null` automatically.:

```sql
SELECT s.student_id, s.first_name || ' ' || s.last_name AS full_name
     , g.gender AS chk_female
FROM   student s
LEFT   JOIN gender g ON g.gender_id = s.gender_id AND g.gender = 'Female';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AIhPSJf9)

This second query is for situations where the `gender_id` of 'Female' is not readily known already, or 'Female' is really a variable.

Since both `first_name` and `last_name` are `NOT NULL`, plain concatenation is fine. else consider null-safe concatenation with  `concat_ws()`. See:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select/19943343#19943343)

Aside: you do **not** want to use the data type `char(n)`. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a JOIN for this, but if you were to use one I would suggest an OUTER join instead of INNER. See this:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/YBzEtnOv