# NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints, postgresql-9.2

I have a table in Postgres which currently has a `NOT NULL` constraint on it's `email` column. This table also has a `phone` column which is optional. I would like the system to accept some records without `email` but only if these have `phone` as `NOT NULL`. In other words, I need a `NOT NULL` database constraint such that `CREATE` or `UPDATE` queries succeed without any errors if either or both of `email` or `phone` fields are present.

Extending the above further, is it possible in Postgres, to specify a set of column names, one or more of which should be `NOT NULL` for the record to be successfully updated or created?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[@Igor is quite right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021193/939860), processing a couple of `OR`'ed expressions is fast and simple.

For a long list of columns (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g` in the example), this is shorter and just as fast:

```
CHECK (NOT (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) IS NULL)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bebcb1d7346858152609e0e9c841df99)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/25782/1)</sub>

#### How does it work?

A more verbose form of the above would be:

```
CHECK (NOT ROW(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) IS NULL)
```

`ROW` is redundant syntax here.

Testing a `ROW` expression with `IS NULL` *only* reports `TRUE` if **every single column** is `NULL` - which happens to be exactly what we want to exclude.

It's not possible to simply reverse this expression with `(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) IS NOT NULL`, because that would test whether every single column `IS NOT NULL`. Instead, negate the whole expression with `NOT`. Voilá.

More details in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html).

An expression of the form:

```
CHECK (COALESCE(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) IS NOT NULL)
```

would achieve the same, less elegantly and with a major restriction: only works for columns of *matching data type*, while the check on a `ROW` expression works with *any* mix of data types.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `CHECK` constraint for this.
Something like:

```
CHECK (email is not null OR phone is not null)
```

Details on constraints can be found [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html)