# SQL: NOT NULL constraint on a set of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
   first_name text,
   last_name text,
   ...
)
```

I would like to be able to add users with either a first name, a last name, or both - but I won't allow a user without any name. In other words (thanks, @wildplasser) - at least one column should not be NULL.

```
 INSERT INTO user(first_name, last_name) VALUES ("foo", NULL);  # 1. OK
 INSERT INTO user(first_name, last_name) VALUES ("foo", "bar"); # 2. OK
 INSERT INTO user(first_name, last_name) VALUES (NULL, "bar");  # 3. OK
 INSERT INTO user(first_name, last_name) VALUES (NULL, NULL);   # 4. NOT OK
```

Obviously, a `NOT NULL` constraint on each columns would disable examples 2 and 3.

How can I express a `NOT NULL` constraint on a set of columns in SQL?

Comment: One method is creating a trigger that check both columns, and if both columns are null, raise an exception.

Comment: You mean: *at least* one of the columns should be BOT NULL ?

Comment: would [this](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/45E5627B.5090603@archonet.com) help ?

Comment: [I meant: NOT NULL, obviously] Cannot be imposed by a column constraint , since that could only reference *one* column. So: you'll need a trigger, IMHO.

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021102/not-null-constraint-over-a-set-of-columns?rq=1

Comment: @Turophile Thanks a bunch. Missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE user(
   first_name text,
   last_name text,
   ...,
   CHECK (first_name IS NOT NULL OR last_name IS NOT NULL)
)
```

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct, and referring everybody to the deeper explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021102/not-null-constraint-over-a-set-of-columns?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use query

For example like this

```
INSERT INTO user(first_name) VALUES (NULL);
```

The `lastname` will be `NULL` when the database schema set the column `lastname` allow `NULL`

Hopefully help 
Thanks