# Adding a unique constraint on a nullable column in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

I am having a table with two columns. Want to add unique constraint on both columns. One of the column is nullable.

I m trying with this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT a_unq UNIQUE (a_id, (coalesce(a_name, '')));
```

Its prompting error at or near `"("`

Comment: m confused, why are you using coalesce?? also if possible please confirm the db server you are using newer sql(2008+) server allows you to create Unique constraints with where clause which can be then used conditionally.

Comment: Create partial constraint(Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you uactually need the solution was in [PostgreSQL multiple nullable columns in unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155809/postgresql-multiple-nullable-columns-in-unique-constraint) : just create UNIQUE index on table, it will stop inserts even if it isn't a constraint declared in table definition:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ex_12345 ON example
        (coalesce(FIELD1, -1)
        , coalesce(FIELD2, -1)
        , coalesce(FIELD3, -1)
        , coalesce(FIELD4, -1)
        , coalesce(FIELD5, -1)
        )
        ;
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to use `coalesce` in that case. Just create constraint in the usual way:

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT a_unq UNIQUE (a_id, a_name);
```

Comment: actually one of his column is nullable that's why I think he tried to use coalesce. I think your query will not work in this scenario as it will not allow more that on null values

Comment: Why do you think that the constraint will not allow more than one NULL value?

Comment: @BlindSniper: if that was the case (which it isn't) then `coalesce()` would actually do the wrong thing as you replace null with `''` which indeed means you can have only one combination of a_id and a null value. without coalesce you can add `(1,null), (1,null)` but _with_ coalesce that would be turned into putting `(1,'')` into the index and _that_ will only be allowed once