# How to avoid "blank" insert when inserting data into a view with a trigger & insert procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, view, plpgsql

I'm trying to update tables from `insert` or `update` call on a PostgreSQL view. Here's a simplified example of what I do:

```
[Person] table:
id | lastname | firstname | city | age

[Person_View] table:
id | lastname | firstname | city
```

Here is the trigger and the related procedure :

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_update_person_view
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON
       Person_View FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_person_view_table();
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_person_view_table()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
   BEGIN
      IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
       INSERT INTO Person (id, lastname, firstname)
        VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.lastname, NEW.firstname);
       RETURN NEW;
      ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
       UPDATE Person
        SET id=NEW.id, lastname=NEW.lastname, firstname=NEW.firstname
        WHERE id=OLD.id;
       RETURN NEW;
      END IF;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
$function$;
```

If I do:

```
INSERT INTO Person_View (id, city) VALUES ('3', 'Berlin')
```

A row with only the ID is added to the view and the parent table.

*How can I check in the procedure that columns in which values are being inserted have a "mapping" defined in the procedure and if there ain't any mapped columns, it does not proceed ?*

Comment: In Postgres 9.3+ you do not need rules nor triggers, a view based on a single table is automatically updateable.

Comment: I know, I should have said that this simplified example is automatically updatable. My real situation is that I have views based on multiple tables and I don't want these empty records to occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a check constraint on the table, e.g.:

```
create table person(
    id int primary key, 
    lastname text, 
    firstname text, 
    city text, 
    age int,
    check(coalesce(lastname, firstname, city, age::text) is not null)
);

insert into person (id)
values (1);

ERROR:  new row for relation "person" violates check constraint "person_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, null, null, null).
```

The solution works regardless whether any views based on the table were created or not.

Answer (score 1):

Have a separate trigger & trigger function for `ON DELETE` to simplify. (You are not doing anything `ON DELETE` anyway?)

A `CHECK` constraint like [klin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41130909/939860) seems like a good idea. You don't need `COALESCE` and casting, though. Check a *row* value for NULL.

```
CHECK (NOT ROW(lastname, firstname) IS NULL)  -- ROW keyword is noise
```

This enforces at least one notnull value in the row. Works for any number of columns and any data type.

Note in particular that `ROW(lastname, firstname) IS NOT NULL` is not the same and would not work. Detailed explanation:

- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021102/not-null-constraint-over-a-set-of-columns/21026085#21026085)

If the `CHECK` constraint is not an option, you can use the same expression in a trigger - which should be faster than adding it to the trigger *function*. [The manual on `CREATE TRIGGER`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

> Also, a trigger definition can specify a Boolean `WHEN` condition, which
> will be tested to see whether the trigger should be fired. In
> row-level triggers the `WHEN` condition can examine the old and/or new
> values of columns of the row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_update_person_view
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON Person_View
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NOT (NEW.lastname, NEW.firstname) IS NULL)  -- more columns?
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_person_view_table();
```

If the `WHEN` expression does not evaluate to `TRUE`, the trigger function is not even called - so it `does not proceed` like requested.

---

**However**, I missed your trigger **`INSTEAD OF`**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

> `INSTEAD OF` triggers do not support `WHEN` conditions.

In this case you have to move the check into the function body:

```
IF NOT (NEW.lastname, NEW.firstname) IS NULL THEN
  --  do stuff
END IF;
```

Comment: I get this error: `ERROR:  INSTEAD OF triggers cannot have WHEN conditions ********** Error **********`.

Comment: @kaycee: Oh, sorry. Not for `INSTEAD` triggers. You have to move the check into the function in this case. (Did you consider the `CHECK` constraint?)