# User table for many tables to login

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to build school management system and I'm having trouble designing an optimal database structure. I have Students, Staff and Users tables for login. User table will have login information only (userNumber, password) and Students and Staff will contain personal information. I separated Students and Staff because they contain different personal data. But they both have a userNumber.

```
users(
id,
userNumber,
password
)

students(
id,
studentNumber,
name,
age
)

staff(
id,
staffNumber,
name,
age,
salary,
dateOfHiring,
staffType
)
```

Let's say I'm login in with a userNumber 98242, how can let the system know where should I look, in Students table or Staff table?

I would like some recommendations on database structures.

Comment: And a student can never be staff member? :) And there are no other roles? Like "guest", "advisor", ... And one person can only have one user account? (Or no account at all?)

Answer (score 0):

just add column `userType` to `users` table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few things. You could create a type in the users table and look that up. You could also join the both the tables and then on recieving a record check if the student id or staff id has been returned.

Then your query could be something like

```
SELECT users.id as user_id, students.id, staff.id FROM users 
LEFT JOIN students ON users.id = students.id
LEFT JOIN staff ON users.id = staff.id
WHERE id = 98242
```

Answer (score 0):

[Inheritance:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html)

```
create table persons (
  id,
  name,
  age
);

create table users (
  number,
  password
) inherits (persons);

create table students (
) inherits (users);

create table stuff (
  salary,
  dateOfHiring,
  staffType
) inherits (users);
```

Schematically, something like this.
Using [`tableoid` system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) you could to know the origin of the particular row:

```
select
  *,
  tableoid::regclass -- Prints the origin table name (users, students, stuff, ...)
from users
where number = 98242;
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are only few separate columns for students and staff members, I would keep it simple:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, name      text
, birthday  date  -- never age! bitrots in no time
, student_number int
, staff_number int
, salary       numeric
, hired_at     date
, staff_type   text
, CONSTRAINT one_role_max CHECK (student_number IS NULL
                              OR (staff_number, salary, hired_at, staff_type) IS NULL)
, CONSTRAINT one_role_min CHECK (student_number IS NOT NULL
                              OR (staff_number, salary, hired_at, staff_type) IS NOT NULL)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  user_number int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, person_id   int NOT NULL REFERENCES person
, password    text -- encrypted !
);
```

This way, one person can have 0-n user accounts - which is the typical reality. You can restrict to a single account per person by adding `UNIQUE (person_id)` to table `users`.

The `CHECK` constraint `one_role_max` enforces that either student columns or staff columns must stay NULL.
The `CHECK` constraint `one_role_min` enforces that at least one of both must have any values.
Adapt what must/can be filled in to your needs. The expressions work excellently for the current design. See:

- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021102/not-null-constraint-over-a-set-of-columns/21026085#21026085)

While it's strictly "either/or" and the only student column is `student_number`, this query answers your question:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN student_number IS NULL THEN 'staff' ELSE 'student' END AS user_role
FROM   person
WHERE  person_id = (SELECT person_id FROM users WHERE user_number = 98242);
```

Or remove one or both `CHECK` constraints to allow the same person to be student *and* staff, or neither. Adapt above query accordingly.

You *could* use inheritance for this (like Abelisto demonstrates), but I'd rather stay away from it. There once was the idea of an object-relational DBMS. But the community has largely moved on. It works, but with [caveats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS). Partitioning used to be a major use case. But declarative partitioning in Postgres 10 mostly superseded the inheritance-based implementation. There is not too much interest in it any more.

What about all those empty columns? Am I wasting a lot of space there? The opposite is the case. The disk footprint won't get much smaller than this. NULL storage is very cheap. See:

- [Does not using NULL in PostgreSQL still use a NULL bitmap in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008753/does-not-using-null-in-postgresql-still-use-a-null-bitmap-in-the-header/7383198#7383198)