# Optimize performance for complex array aggregation

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate

I have a table of the following format:

```
Table "my_table"
       Column          |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |
-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+
 foreign_key_column_id | integer                     |           | not null |
 column1_value_1       | character varying           |           | not null |
 column1_value_2       | character varying           |           |          |
 column1_value_3       | character varying           |           |          |
```

There can be multiple rows with same `foreign_key_column_id`.
My goal is to merge all rows of same `foreign_key_column_id` into the following format:

```
foreign_key_column_id
column1::jsonb
```

So that the resulting array is a combination of distinct non-null values of the three columns. (Then I will insert the resulting dataset into a new table)

I have achieved it by the following, but I am sure this is resource-inefficient (too many functions) and because the table I will run it on has close to 100 million rows, I have to care about performance.

```
SELECT
  foreign_key_column_id,
  array_to_json(
    array_remove(
      array(
        SELECT DISTINCT unnest(
          array_agg(
            array[
              column1_value_1,
              column1_value_2,
              column1_value_3
            ]
          )
        )
      ),
      NULL
    )
  ) AS column1
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY foreign_key_column_id
```

My actual, complete situation:

```
-- initial table
TABLE public.my_table (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  foreign_key_column_id integer NOT NULL,
  column1_value_1 character varying NOT NULL,
  column1_value_2 character varying,
  column1_value_3 character varying,
  column2_value_1 character varying NOT NULL,
  column2_value_2 character varying,
  column2_value_3 character varying,
  column3_value_1 character varying(90) NOT NULL,
  column3_value_2 character varying(90),
  column3_value_3 character varying(90)
)

-- desired table into which I will insert the aggregated select

TABLE public.my_new_table (
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  foreign_key_column_id bigint NOT NULL,
  headlines jsonb NOT NULL,
  descriptions jsonb NOT NULL
);

-- sample data
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+--
id                    | 111
foreign_key_column_id | 12
column1_value_1       | Foo
column1_value_2       |
column1_value_3       |
column2_value_1       | Foo %{1}
column2_value_2       | 
column2_value_3       | Foo %{3}
column3_value_1       | Foo : Bar 
column3_value_2       |
column3_value_3       |
-[ RECORD 2 ]-------+--
id                    | 222
foreign_key_column_id | 12
column1_value_1       | Bar %{1}
column1_value_3       | 
column1_value_2       | Bar %{2}
column2_value_1       | Bar
column2_value_2       |
column2_value_3       |
column3_value_1       | Qux
column3_value_2       |
column3_value_3       |
-[ RECORD 3 ]-------+--
id                    | 33
foreign_key_column_id | 1234
column1_value_1       | Foo
column1_value_2       |
column1_value_3       |
column2_value_1       | Baz %{1}
column2_value_3       | 
column2_value_2       | Baz %{2}
column3_value_1       | 
column3_value_2       | Hello world
column3_value_3       |

-- expected output
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+--
id                    | 1
foreign_key_column_id | 12
column1               | ["Foo", "Bar %{1}", "Bar %{2}"]
column2               | ["Foo %{1}", "Foo %{3}", "Bar"]
column3               | ["Foo : Bar ", "Qux"]

-[ RECORD 2 ]-------+--
id                    | 2
foreign_key_column_id | 1234
column1               | ["Foo"]
column2               | ["Baz %{1}", "Baz %{2}"]
column3               | ["Hello world"]
```

Comment: If you want all distinct values of the three columns for each foreign key, you will have to process 300 million values at one point or the other. So I don't think there is a more efficient way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added sample data and output, thanks for looking into it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name also, I was trying to understand whether for my new table a jsonb is the proper datastructure to use. I need to store a limited amount of string entries in array, so need array column.

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be that `text[]` is a bit more efficient than `jsonb`

Comment: Consider the fiddle in my answer: That's a much more forthcoming way to provide test data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be substantially faster: a `LATERAL JOIN` to a `VALUES` expression, effectively unpivoting the columns to rows:

```sql
SELECT foreign_key_column_id
     , jsonb_agg(DISTINCT c.col1) AS column1
FROM   my_table t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES
     (column1_value_1)
   , (column1_value_2)
   , (column1_value_3)
   ) c(col1) ON col1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a0196462a6125929532264912ee78c24)*

Most importantly, the **big table is only scanned once**.

`NULL` values are removed early. Since `column1_value_1` is defined `NOT NULL` there is always at least one row to join, and we never re-introduce `NULL` values by way of "no row". (Else we'd add a `FILTER` clause like below.)

Plus some other simplifications.

Related:

- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102702/3684)

To process all at once (your added table with 3x3 columns):

```sql
SELECT foreign_key_column_id
     , jsonb_agg(DISTINCT c.col1) AS column1
     , jsonb_agg(DISTINCT c.col2) FILTER (WHERE c.col2 IS NOT NULL) AS column2 -- !
     , jsonb_agg(DISTINCT c.col3) FILTER (WHERE c.col3 IS NOT NULL) AS column3
FROM   my_table3 t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   VALUES
     (column1_value_1, column2_value_1, column3_value_1)
   , (column1_value_2, column2_value_2, column3_value_2)
   , (column1_value_3, column2_value_3, column3_value_3)
   ) c(col1, col2, col3) ON NOT (col1, col2, col3) IS NULL  -- !
GROUP  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a0196462a6125929532264912ee78c24)*

Still ***a single scan*** ove the big table.

Removing `NULL` values is not as simple, as we cannot collapse all  three columns for a single NULL. But we can still drop rows with only NULL values right away. Testing ROW values for `NULL` is tricky. Note the syntax! `NOT (col1, col2, col3) IS NULL`. See:

- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021102/not-null-constraint-over-a-set-of-columns/21026085#21026085)

Remove remaining NULL values with the `FILTER` clause in the outer aggregate. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

We don't need `FILTER` for `column1` as source columns are defined `NOT NULL`.