# Aggragate inner join column with prepended value from third column

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I have three tables. Leads, Notes and Users.

```
leads
- id
- name

notes
- id
- lead_id
- content
- user_id

users
- id
- name
```

I would like to construct a query to return new table with two columns

```
Lead name | Notes
John      | Mary - Note 1 ### John - Note 2
```

First column is straightforward. Every lead has a name. Second column however is a tricky one. I want to aggregate all notes to single column with addition to prepending note's author's name.

I wrote a query with second column that has aggregated notes.

```
 SELECT leads.name AS name,
        string_agg(notes.content, ' ### ') AS leads_notes,
 FROM leads
 INNER JOIN notes ON notes.lead_id = leads.id
 GROUP BY leads.id
```

But note's author name (`users.name`) I do not how to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting is misleading. Single quotes are not for identifiers.
Also your joins are twisted. You can't join users to leads directly. `leads` has no `user_id` ...

```
SELECT ls.name
      , string_agg(concat_ws(' - ', u.name, n.content)
                  , ' ### ') AS leads_notes
FROM   leads l
JOIN   notes n ON n.lead_id = l.id
JOIN   users u ON u.id = n.user_id
GROUP  BY l.id;
```

Fixed the basic structure.

Concatenate `name` and `content` with [**`concat_ws()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) (multiple values from the *same row*) before you aggregate with `string_agg()` (multiple values *across rows*).

If `users.name` and `notes.content` are defined `NOT NULL`, you can just concatenate instead:

```
u.name || ' - ' || n.content
```

Details:

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/postgresql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)

You also may want to order the elements per lead in a non-arbitrary fashion:

```
string_agg( ... ORDER BY u.name, u.id)
```