# Query performance with concatenation and LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, concatenation, postgresql-performance

Can someone explain the performance difference between these 3 queries?

`concat()` function:

```
explain analyze 
select * from person 
where (concat(last_name, ' ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) like '%Ива%');

Seq Scan on person  (cost=0.00..4.86 rows=1 width=15293) (actual time=0.032..0.140 rows=6 loops=1)
  Filter: (pg_catalog.concat(last_name, ' ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) ~~ '%Ива%'::text)
Total runtime: 0.178 ms
```

SQL standard concatenation with `||`:

```
explain analyze 
select * from person 
where ((last_name || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || middle_name) like '%Ива%');

Seq Scan on person  (cost=0.00..5.28 rows=1 width=15293) (actual time=0.023..0.080 rows=6 loops=1)
  Filter: ((((((last_name)::text || ' '::text) || (first_name)::text) || ' '::text) || (middle_name)::text) ~~ '%Ива%'::text)
Total runtime: 0.121 ms
```

Search fields separately:

```
explain analyze 
select * from person 
where (last_name like '%Ива%') or (first_name like '%Ива%') or (middle_name like '%Ива%');

Seq Scan on person  (cost=0.00..5.00 rows=1 width=15293) (actual time=0.018..0.060 rows=6 loops=1)
  Filter: (((last_name)::text ~~ '%Ива%'::text) OR ((first_name)::text ~~ '%Ива%'::text) OR ((middle_name)::text ~~ '%Ива%'::text))
Total runtime: 0.097 ms
```

Why is `concat()` slowest one and why are several `like` conditions faster?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why does `pg.concat` is slowest one and several `like` is faster?

Comment: @ma3a try `last_name||' '||first_name||' '||middle_name`(i guess in your case manual  concatenation is better than concat())

Comment: @vivek see second query, it's a bit faster than pg.concat, and it's strange, cause first and second query almost the same. It's not production code, i just interested in why this queries running slow

Comment: @ma3a because `concat()` is _function_ when you execute your select postgres call that `concat()` for the operation

Comment: @vivek, so this is overhead for calling function on each row?

Comment: @ma3a In your case it's an overhead

Comment: Re-run those statements in a different order. The differences in the runtimes are small enough to be caused by caching of the underlying data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i've made rerun in different order(reverse), and there is no changes: 0.096, 0.120, 0.182

Comment: A test on a table with only 6 rows doesn't mean a lot. And this query is so fast that any bit fart of your computer could be responsible for the differences in timing.

Comment: @Frank Heikens table not 6 rows, `select count(*) from person` produce `43`

Comment: @ma3a: And does that make any difference? It's still an almost empty table.... Create a million records and run your tests again. A sequential scan that runs within a millisecond can never be "slow", no matter what.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not a concrete answer, the following might help you to reach some conclusions:

1. Calling `concat` to concatenate the three strings, or using the `||` operator, results in postgres having to allocate a new buffer to hold the concatenated string, then copy the characters into it. This has to be done for each row. Then the buffer has to be deallocated at the end.
2. In the case where you are ORing together three conditions, postgres may only have to evaluate only one or maybe two of them to decide if it has to include the row.
3. It is possible that expression evaluation using the `||` operator might be more efficient, or perhaps more easily optimizable, compared with a function call to `concat`. I would not be surprised to find that there is some special case handling for internal operators.
4. As mentioned in the comments, your sample is too small to make proper conclusions anyway. At the level of a fraction of a millisecond, other noise factors can distort the result.

Comment: "of a few hundred milliseconds", the test cases are even worse, all tests ran within a millisecond, the slowest test took just 0.178 millisecond.

Answer (score 5):

What you have observed so far is interesting, but only a minor cost overhead for concatenating strings.

The **much more important** difference between these expressions does not show in your minimal test case without indexes.

The first two examples are not [**sargable**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217983) (unless you build a tailored expression index):

```
where concat(last_name, ' ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) like '%Ива%'
where (last_name || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || middle_name) like '%Ива%'
```

While this one is:

```
where last_name like '%Ива%' or first_name like '%Ива%' or middle_name like '%Ива%'
```

I.e., it can use a plain trigram index to great effect (order of columns is unimportant in a GIN index):

```
CREATE INDEX some_idx ON person USING gin (first_name  gin_trgm_ops
                                         , middle_name gin_trgm_ops
                                         , last_name   gin_trgm_ops);
```

Instructions:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

#### Incorrect test if `null` is possible

[`concat()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is generally slightly more expensive than simple string concatenation with `||`. It is also **different**: If any of the input strings is `null`, the concatenated result is also `null` in your second case, but not in your first, since `concat()` just ignores `null` input. But you'd still get a useless space character in the result.

Detailed explanation:

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)

If you are looking for a clean, elegant expression (about the same cost), use [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) instead:

```
concat_ws( ' ', last_name, first_name, middle_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

This query has overhead for calling function on each row

```
explain analyze 
select * from person 
where (concat(last_name, ' ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) like '%Ива%');
```

this query is faster cause no additional operation executed

```
explain analyze 
select * from person 
where (last_name like '%Ива%') or (first_name like '%Ива%') or (middle_name like '%Ива%');
```