# Replace a string with another string from a list depending on the value

Tags: postgresql, replace, postgresql-8.4

Let's say I have this string: `'2015/4/21 (Tuesday)'`. I want to replace 'Tuesday' with another string, for example: 'cat'. The result should be: `'2015/4/21 (cat)'`.

But I also want it to be dynamic, if it's 'Tuesday', then 'cat'. If it's 'Monday', then it's dog, etc.

How do I do this in PostgreSQL 8.4?

There is a similar post: [postgresql - replace all instances of a string within text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060526/postgresql-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-text-field)

But mine needs to replace something *dynamic* depending on the day and that post replaces a known value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [postgresql - replace all instances of a string within text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060526/postgresql-replace-all-instances-of-a-string-within-text-field)

Comment: Would you consider putting the translation into a two-column lookup table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a couple of *mutually exclusive* replacements, nested replace statements are the simplest and fastest way. Just [like @Gordon suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29761482/939860).

But that does not scale well for more than a few replacements and there are **pitfalls**:

#### Substrings

It becomes ambiguous when strings can be substrings of each other. Consider these two expressions:

```
SELECT replace((replace('2015 (Monday)', 'day', 'snake'), 'Monday', 'dog')
     , replace((replace('2015 (Monday)', 'Monday', 'dog'), 'day', 'snake');
```

The result depends on the sequence of replacements. You have to define priorities. Typically you would replace longer strings first.

#### Chains

Then there is also the possibility that one replacement might create a match for the next:

```
SELECT replace((replace('2015 (Sunday)', 'Sun', 'Mon'), 'Monday', 'dog')
     , replace((replace('2015 (Sunday)', 'Monday', 'dog'), 'Sun', 'Mon');
```

Again, you have to define priorities.
Every replacement possibly influences the next. With more than a few replacements, this becomes murky and error prone quickly. Also very hard to maintain if replacements can change.

As I said, with just the days of the week, nested `replace()` statements are fine. That's not actually "dynamic". If weekdays were just to illustrate the problem and you actually have to deal with more cases or truly dynamic strings, I would consider a different approach. Find completely **dynamic solutions** in this related answer:

- [How to replace all subsets of characters based on values of other tables in pl/pgsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666596/how-to-replace-all-subsets-of-characters-based-on-values-of-other-tables-in-pl-p/29693497#29693497)

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and used the nested replace. :)

Comment: Can you mostly eliminate the concerns by using a delimiter around the tokens to replace?  If the initial input string is the result of a query, concat the delimiters in the SELECT?

Comment: @grantwparks: Not sure I understand. Please ask your question as new question. You can always link to this one for context.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a recursive function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_recursive(search text, from_to text[][])
RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (array_length(from_to,1) > 1) THEN
        RETURN replace_recursive(
            replace(search, from_to[1][1], from_to[1][2]),
            from_to[2:array_upper(from_to,1)]
        );
    ELSE
        RETURN replace(search, from_to[1][1], from_to[1][2]);
    END IF;
END;$$;
```

Result:

```
select replace_recursive('from1, from2, from3', array[['from1', 'to1'], ['from2', 'to2']]);

┌───────────────────┐
│ replace_recursive │
├───────────────────┤
│ to1, to2, from3   │
└───────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with nested `replace()`:

```
select replace(replace(str, 'Tuesday', 'cat'), 'Monday', 'dog')
```

If the value is not in the string, nothing happens.

Comment: Is it possible to use regular expression type of replace? Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin . . . Probably, but there doesn't seem to be a need.