# how to combine two columns of integer in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select col1, col2
from ...
where...
```

which gives:

```
col1  col2
5
       17
4       5
12
5
       20
4      17
2       3
```

I want to convert it to one column with no duplicates as follows:

```
col3
5
17
4
12
20
2
3
```

How can I do that?
I read this topic [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column) but it's not what I need... operator `||` won't help here.

**Edit:**
**col3** is simply a list of all numbers that appear in **col2** and **col1**.

Comment: third row has 4, not 5 - why? is there a rule to use first column if both specified?.. try `select coalesce(col1,col2) from table` - it will use col1, and if col1 is null, then col2

Comment: @VaoTsun The logic is show me all numbers that appear in any of the columns but with no duplicates. col3 is simply a list of all numbers that appear in col2 and col1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you need `union`

```
select col1 as col3 from t where col1 is not null
union
select col2 as col3 from t where col2 is not null
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select coalesce(col1,col2) 
from table
```

it will use col1, and if col1 is null, then col2

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not
>   null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often
>   used to substitute a default value for null values when data is
>   retrieved for display

Comment: coalesce is not enough... I edited my example to show why.  The number 3 will never appear in the final result using coalesce.

Comment: in your sample between 20.....2, 3 are missing 4, 17 - is it because you want distinct values only? I answered thinkng you want to **combine** two columns, not just select both columns as one

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COALESCE function as documented at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL ; it returns the first of its arguments that is not null:

```
yesql# select col1, col2, coalesce(col1, col2) from foo;
 col1 │ col2 │ coalesce 
══════╪══════╪══════════
    5 │    ¤ │        5
    ¤ │   17 │       17
    4 │    5 │        4
   12 │    ¤ │       12
    5 │    ¤ │        5
    ¤ │   20 │       20
    4 │   17 │        4
(7 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

> col3 is simply a list of all numbers that appear in col2 and col1.

In that case, this might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT col1
FROM ...
WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT col2
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```