# Attribute notation for function call gives error

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

**Attribute notation function call gives error when current schema is different from one of function.**

I have created a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION pub.FullName(pub.reps)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
       select ($1.fname || ' ' || $1.lname)
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I am trying to call the function with attribute notation as described in [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE)):

```
select r.fullname from pub.reps r;
```

But get an error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "fullname" does not exist
> ```

Query with functional notation works fine:

```
select pub.fullname(r.*) from pub.reps r;
```

Database has been migrated from PostgreSQL 10 with backup/restore.

`Select version()` gives: `PostgreSQL 11.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

**UPD**. Found out that if I set `pub` schema as default, then `select r.fullname from pub.reps r` works with no error.

Comment: test database on which server? why the mixed case spelling? did you use double qoutes anywhere?

Comment: Mixed case for readability only. It does not affect the result. Server is the same as for the first database - my own laptop.

Comment: I've found out that it depends on current schema. If I set up pub schema as default, then `select r.FullName from pub.reps r` works. Otherwise I get an error.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, thank you for detailed answer and for improving my post. Now it looks much better. Also for db<>fiddle link. Which should be a good tool. As I understand there is no way to use attribute functionality without modifying search path (for example with explicitly using schema in query). So I would better wait for Postgres 12.

Comment: The schema of the function has to be in the search path as there is no way to schema-qualify the attribute (turned into a function). Strictly speaking, you do not *have* to modify the `search_path`: you can always create the function in a schema that's already there, `pg_catalog` as a measure of last resort. (Though I'd rather avoid putting user objects there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the root of the problem yourself. To be precise: the schema of the function `pub` has to be listed *anywhere* in the current **`search_path`**, does not have to be the "default" or "current" schema (the first one in the list). Related:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

So Postgres did not find the function. Postgres 11 isn't different from Postgres 10 in this regard. There are some noteworthy, related developments, though. You mentioned:

> Database has been migrated from PostgreSQL 10 with backup/restore.

Consider this subtle change pointed out in the [release notes for Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.9.4):

> - Consider syntactic form when disambiguating function versus column references (Tom Lane)
>
>   When ***`x`*** is a table name or composite column, PostgreSQL has
>     traditionally considered the syntactic forms ***`f(x)`*** and ***`x.f`*** to be
>     equivalent, allowing tricks such as writing a function and then using
>     it as though it were a computed-on-demand column. However, if both
>     interpretations are feasible, the column interpretation was always
>     chosen, leading to surprising results if the user intended the
>     function interpretation. Now, if there is ambiguity, the
>     interpretation that matches the syntactic form is chosen.

So, **if** there was a column `fullname` in table `reps` *and also* the function `pub.fullname(pub.reps)` you display, Postgres 10, even with functional notation, would still chose the *column*:

```
SELECT fullname(r) FROM reps r;  -- resolves to column if it exists, ignoring function
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=deb88e6dc62311c28ee65a57d82ae7ce)* for Postgres 10

Postgres 11 (more reasonably) choses the function:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=14cad1559687ac0e0bc8853e377814bb)* for Postgres 11

**Postgres 12** (currently beta) eventually implements true generated columns. [The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.5.5.5)

> - Add support for generated columns (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> The content of generated columns are computed from expressions
>   (including references to other columns in the same table) rather than
>   being specified by `INSERT` or `UPDATE` commands.

Only **`STORED`** generated columns made it into this release, though. The (more interesting IMO) [**`VIRTUAL`** variant was postponed for a later release](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/57c70b3e-b29a-ad08-cdce-746f6d561e3d%402ndquadrant.com). (Not in Postgres 13, yet.)

Your table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE pub.reps (
  reps_id  int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY 
, fname    text NOT NULL
, lname    text NOT NULL
, fullname text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (fname || ' ' || lname) STORED
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=461a4ba73cc0f248d7aaea20ea49daf0)*

I declared `fname` and `lname` columns `NOT NULL`. Else, your simple concatenation (`fname || ' ' || lname`) is a trap. See:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select/19943343#19943343)
- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)