# Postgresql generated column fails when concating not null columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table definition in pgAdmin4:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdr_event
(
    id bigint primary key generated always as identity,
    start_time timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    end_time timestamptz NULL,
    group_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    environment VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,     
    level VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,           
    schema VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,      
    instance INTEGER NOT NULL,            
    hive_instance_db_name VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (group_id||'_'||environment||'_'||level||'_'||schema||'_'||instance) STORED,
    hive_static_db_name VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (group_id||'_'||environment||'_'||level||'_'||schema) STORED,
);
```

this fails with

```
ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable
SQL state: 42P17
```

Why does postgres consider the concat mutable when the dependent columns are all NOT NULL?  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369) suggests it should work

Is there anyway to create a concat-ed generated column without creating a custom concat function?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try keeping the involved columns of the same type, e.g. casting `instance` to `text` should do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdr_event
(
    id bigint primary key generated always as identity,
    start_time timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    end_time timestamptz NULL,
    group_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    environment VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,     
    level VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,           
    schema VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,      
    instance INTEGER NOT NULL,            
    hive_instance_db_name VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (group_id||'_'||environment||'_'||level||'_'||schema||'_'||instance::text) STORED,
    hive_static_db_name VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (group_id||'_'||environment||'_'||level||'_'||schema) STORED
);
```

Consider using `text` instead of `varchar`.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f5eef90ba8be98afeb309f5bf122d8c4)

Comment: Only `instance` is the problem. And casting it to `text` will do. No need to cut off `schema`. I'm still wondering why the implicit cast would be considered not immutable though?

Comment: @stickybit that's right! I oversaw it was an integer .. thanks for pointing out. +1 just edited my answer

Comment: @stickybit I'm still wondering the same thing and still searching for an explanation :D

Comment: @JimJones thanks, that works.  yeah i tested the concat worked as a select, using the implicit cast.  Seems weird you need to cast it here.  hey ho