# Generate value from columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to have a generated column, which value will be the concated string from two other values:

```
 CREATE TABLE public.some_data (
    user_name varchar NULL,
    domain_name serial NOT NULL,

    email GENERATED ALWAYS AS (user_name ||'@'||domain_name) stored
 );
```

But that gives `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALWAYS"`

Comment: You still have the declare the data type; Try `email text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (user_name ||'@'||domain_name) stored`

Comment: this produces an error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8540dcd1198753520754028e5fcda379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the data type for the column as @Belayer commented.

And then you need to explicitly cast `domain_name` as `text` (or some `varchar`). Otherwise you'll get an error that the expression isn't immutable as @nbk commented. `serial` is translated to be basically an `integer` and for whatever reason implicit casts of an `integer` in concatenations are considered not immutable by the engine. We had that just recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68740206/postgresql-generated-column-fails-when-concating-not-null-columns/68740847#comment121484692_68740847).

So overall, using the given types for the columns, you want something like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.some_data
             (user_name varchar NULL,
              domain_name serial NOT NULL,
              email text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (user_name || '@' || domain_name::text) STORED);
```

But it's a little weird that a domain name is a `serial`? Shouldn't that be a `text` or similar? Then you wouldn't need the cast of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `IMMUTABLE` function to achieve the generate column, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_email_concat(varchar,int) returns text as 
$$
    select $1 ||'@'||$2::text;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE ;

CREATE TABLE public.some_data (
    user_name varchar NULL,
    domain_name serial NOT NULL,
    email text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (generate_email_concat(user_name,domain_name)) stored
 );

INSERT into some_data(user_name) values ('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to concatenate varchar and integer. You have to cast domain_name. This works for me

```
CREATE TABLE public.some_data (
    user_name varchar NULL,
    domain_name serial NOT NULL,
    email varchar GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN user_name IS NULL THEN 'noname'||'@'||domain_name::text ELSE user_name ||'@'||domain_name::text END) STORED
 );
```