# Table field with combined fields values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, field, combinations

I want to create a table ex. **Person**. Where Person has **name** and **last_name**. I want to add a third field called **full_name** which is the *combination of name and last name*.

```
CREATE TABLE person(
   id BIGINT,
   name VARCHAR(50),
   last_name VARCHAR(50),
   full_name VARCHAR(100) *COMBINE(name,last_name)
)
```

I'm aware that I can create a function like explained here [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column) like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION combined(rec person)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  SELECT $1.name || $1.last_name;
$$; 

SELECT *, person.combined FROM person;
```

But I would like to declare it in the table as another field, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a computed column:

```
alter table person add column full_name text generated always as
    (name || last_name) stored;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9b82e054ccfbc9edf6ec634c016015b4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It throws an error syntax error at or near "GENERATED"

Comment: CREATE TABLE person
(
    id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('id_sequence')
        CONSTRAINT pk_id_person PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name       VARCHAR(50),
    last_name        VARCHAR(50) NOT null,
    display_name     TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( first_name || last_name ) stored
);

Comment: @CésarCastroAroche . . . Ahh.  Generated columns were added in Postgres 12.  You might just want to use a view.

Answer (score 0):

**In Postgres 12:**

```
CREATE TABLE person ( 
     id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('id_sequence') CONSTRAINT pk_id_person 
             PRIMARY KEY, 
     first_name VARCHAR(50), 
     last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT null, 
     full_name VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( first_name || last_name ) stored );
```

**Older Postgres:**

Create a table without full name. And add a view that combines the field like this:

```
CREATE VIEW person_view AS
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, (first_name || last_name) as full_name
FROM person;
```