# Adding a space seperating string

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to add space between two name columns concatenated in SQL ?

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.first_name, a.last_name), f.title, f.description, f.length
FROM actor a
JOIN film_actor fa
ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
JOIN film f
ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
```

[snapshot of result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzGvD.png)

i want to have space between names like "PenelopeGuiness" to "Penelope Guiness"

Comment: `select  CONCAT('adrian', ' ',  'klaver'); adrian klaver`. From docs(where you should have started) [String Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html): *concat ( val1 "any" [, val2 "any" [, ...] ] ) → text ... Concatenates the text representations of all the arguments. NULL arguments are ignored.*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add `' '` inside CONCATE parameters but id did not work!
Anyway, I just found below solution and it worked.

```
SELECT a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name AS full_name
```

Comment: `concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name)` will most certainly work

Comment: Look at my comment to your question and you will see it does indeed work. If there was an error when you did it then it is due to something else. To your question add what you tried and the complete error message.

Comment: @m.aljundi Are you perhaps using oracle? Oracle limits `concat` to just two arguments; therefore you need pipes in oracle. If you're using oracle, then you mis-tagged your question.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/RSbpNWBN

Answer (score 0):

Each of these concatenates a space character in between:

```
first_name || ' ' || last_name
concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)
concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name)
```

(The first form with basic concatenation operator being very slightly cheaper.)

But each form handles **NULL** input differently. You typically want "NULL-safe" concatenation with `concat_ws()` if that can happen. Detailed assessment:

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.first_name, " ", a.last_name), f.title, f.description, f.length
FROM actor a
JOIN film_actor fa
ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
JOIN film f
ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
```

Comment: Strings need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL: `" "`  needs to b `' '`