# Find possible duplicates in two columns ignoring case and special characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, pattern-matching, case-insensitive

#### Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*), name, number
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY name, number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

It sometimes fails to find duplicates between lower case and upper case.
E.g.: `sunny` and `Sunny` don't show up as a duplicates.
So how to find all possible duplicates in PostgreSQL for two columns.

Comment: When you say "special characters" do you mean that you want "Soft" and "$s^o&f!t" to be equal? Or are you talking about accented characters, where you want "Cafe" and "Café" to be matched as equal?

Comment: @CraigRinger yup!!! it is also a possiblity

Comment: which? Or do you mean "both of the above" ?

Comment: "Soft" and "$s^o&f!t"  @CraigRinger

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### [`lower()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL)/ [`upper()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL)

Use one of these to fold characters to either lower or upper case. Special characters are not affected:

```
SELECT count(*), lower(name), number
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY lower(name), number
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

#### [`unaccent()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html#id-1.11.7.52.8)

If you actually want to ignore diacritic signs, like your comments imply, install the additional module [`unaccent`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html), which provides a text search dictionary that removes accents and also the general purpose function `unaccent()`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

Makes it very simple:

```
SELECT lower(unaccent('Büßercafé'));
```

Result:

```
busercafe
```

This doesn't strip non-letters. Add `regexp_replace()` like @Craig mentioned for that:

```
SELECT lower(unaccent(regexp_replace('$s^o&f!t Büßercafé', '\W', '', 'g') ));
```

Result:

```
softbusercafe
```

You can even build a functional index on top of that:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

Comment: is there something similar to RLIKE in postgre

Comment: @soul: Case insensitive `LIKE`? [`ILIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE).

Comment: In mysql there is function RLIKE ... is ILIKE similar to it in postgre  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: You can use the [regular expression match operator **`~`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) for a similar purpose as MySQL's [RLIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Comment: I have seen from the comments, you want to "unaccent", too. Well, there is a much simpler and proven way. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know about `unaccent`. Useful especially since it works with tsearch2. I still think the whole idea of "unaccenting" is pretty terrible, but if you're stuck with terrible data I guess you have to do terrible things.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Unaccenting can be *extremely useful* to keep the rate of alpha errors low (undesirable rows found) while also reducing beta errors (desired rows not found) in a fuzzy search with human input, especially in languages with lots of (more or less optional) accents, i.e. most languages that are not English.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter there is a problem with the query it is not able to find the duplicates in the name!!! but wen we do `group by name having count(name)>1` i can get the duplicates

Comment: @soul: I suppose you post a new question with your query and some sample data. The problem should be easy to find with this information. You can always link to this question for context.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter can u suggest a proper question for this!! like i will update the question !!! need to update ur query with the records is it

Comment: @soul: Post a *new* question showing the exact query and and example values that it fails with. I don't have enough information to work with (I don't quite understand what your problem is).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter posted it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133599/query-not-able-to-find-the-duplicates-between-the-name

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL by default is case sensitive. You can force it to be case-insensitive during searches by converting all values to a single case:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), lower(name), number FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY lower(name), number HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

- **NOTE**: This has not been tested in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

(Updated answer after clarification from poster): The idea of "unaccenting" or stripping accents (dicratics) is generally bogus. It's OK-ish if you're matching data to find out if some misguided user or application munged `résumé` into `resume`, but it's totally wrong to change one into the other, as they're different words. Even then it'll only kind-of work, and should be combined with a string-similarity matching system like [trigrams](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) or [Levenshtein distances](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html).

The idea of "unaccenting" presumes that any accented character has a single valid equivalent unaccented character, or at least that any given accented character is replaced with at most one unaccented character in an ascii-ized representation of the word. That simply isn't true; in one language `ö` might be a "u" sound, while in another it might be a long "oo", and the "ascii-ized" spelling conventions might reflect that. Thus, in language the correct "un-accenting" of the made-up dummy-word "Tapö" might be "Tapu" and in another this imaginary word might be ascii-ized to "Tapoo". In neither case will the "un-accented" form of "Tapo" match what people actually write when forced into the ascii character set. Words with dicratics may also be ascii-ized into a hyphenated word.

You can [see this in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_terms_with_diacritical_marks) with ligatures, where the word [`dæmon`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28disambiguation%29) is ascii-ized `daemon`. If you stripped the ligature you'd get `dmon` which wouldn't match `daemon`, the common spelling. The same is true of `æther` which is typically ascii-ized to `aether` or `ether`. You can also see this in German with [ß](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#German_.C3.9F), typically "expanded" as `ss`.

### If you *must* attempt to "un-accent", "normalize" accents or "strip" accents:

You can use a character class regular expression to strip out all but a specified set of characters. In this case we use the `\W` escape (shorthand for the character class `[^[:alnum:]_]` [as per the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)) to exclude "symbols" but not accented characters:

```
regress=# SELECT regexp_replace(lower(x),'\W','','g') 
          FROM ( VALUES ('$s^o&f!t'),('Café') ) vals(x);
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 soft
 café
(2 rows)
```

If you want to filter out accented chars too you can define your own character class:

```
regress=# SELECT regexp_replace(lower(x),'[^a-z0-9]','','g')
          FROM ( VALUES ('$s^o&f!t'),('Café') ) vals(x);
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 soft
 caf
(2 rows)
```

If you actually intended to *substitute* some accented characters for similar unaccented characters, you could use `translate` as per [this wiki article](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strip_accents_from_strings,_and_output_in_lowercase):

```
regress=# SELECT translate(
        lower(x),
        'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
        'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu'
    )
    FROM ( VALUES ('$s^o&f!t'),('Café') ) vals(x);

 translate 
-----------
 $s^o&f!t
 cafe
(2 rows)
```

Comment: i used php regular expression stored it to a variable and did it!!! it got a length process!!! anyways thanks mate... will accept ur answer!!!